# Git remote branch deleted, but still it appears in 'branch -a'

Tags: git, git-branch

Let's say I had a branch named `coolbranch` in my repository.

Now, I decided to delete it (both remotely and locally) with:

```
git push origin :coolbranch
git branch -D coolbranch
```

Great!
Now the branch is really deleted.

But when I run

```
git branch -a
```

I still get:

```
remotes/origin/coolbranch
```

Something to notice, is that when I clone a new repository, everything is fine and `git branch -a` doesn't show the branch.

I want to know - is there a way to delete the branch from the `branch -a` list without cloning a new instance?

Comment: Related: [Delete a Git branch both locally and remotely](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2003505/456814).

Comment: If you `git fetch -p` (or `git pull -p`) then remote branches will be pruned.

Answer (score 978, accepted):

`git remote prune origin` will remove all such stale branches. That's probably what you'd want in most cases, but if you want to just remove that particular remote-tracking branch, you should do:

```
git branch -d -r origin/coolbranch
```

(The `-r` is easy to forget...)

`-r` in this case will "List or delete (if used with `-d`) the remote-tracking branches." according to the Git documentation found here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch

Comment: `git remote prune origin` or any form of `git fetch --prune` flagging did not work for me in my case.  ...But `git branch -d -r origin/feature/branch-name` did work. I'm not sure if it had something to do with it being under the `feature` namespace (git flow) but that's how it went down, in case any googlers find that happens to them.

Comment: Is there a reason this is necessary? Seems really bad to leave these non-existent branch names in the list and not automatically prune them.

Comment: @akronymn Agreed. There's a lot of odd default behavior in git

Comment: @akronymn there is a config flag you can set to do it automatically : set `fetch.prune` to `true` (cf [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59792628/11384184))

Comment: git branch -d -r origin/sprint#12A works for me

Answer (score 415):

Try:

```
git remote prune origin
```

From the [Git remote documentation](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html):

**prune**

> Deletes all stale
>   remote-tracking branches under <name>.
>   These stale branches have already been
>   removed from the remote repository
>   referenced by <name>, but are still
>   locally available in "remotes/<name>".
>   
>  With --dry-run option, report
>   what branches will be pruned, but do
>   not actually prune them.

Comment: For completeness: it must be similar to `git pull --prune` mentioned at http://stackoverflow.com/a/17983126/94687 And: `git remote update --prune`

Answer (score 291):

Don't forget the awesome

```
git fetch -p
```

which fetches and prunes all origins.

Comment: For completeness: it must be the same as `git remote prune origin` and similar to `git pull --prune` mentioned at http://stackoverflow.com/a/6127884/94687 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/17983126/94687 respectively. And: `git remote update --prune`

Comment: But branches will be still visible if u run `git branch -a`

Comment: @NikhilSahu: I'm not seeing the remote branches that were removed anymore with `git branch -a`

Answer (score 37):

In our particular case, we use Stash as our remote Git repository. We tried all the previous answers and nothing was working. We ended up having to do the following:

```
git branch –D branch-name (delete from local)
git push origin :branch-name (delete from remote)
```

Then when users went to pull changes, they needed to do the following:

```
git fetch -p
```

Comment: `git branch -d branch-name` worked for me. Notice `-D` to `-d`. In fact when I tried with upper case D `-D` it created a new branch with name -D

Comment: the "-D" is a way of forcing the delete regardless of its push or merge status. Obviously be careful using it, but in a lot of cases, it has been necessary.

Comment: What does the `:` stand for in `git push origin :branch-name`?

Comment: @Giraldi `:` stands for _fromLocalBranch_ : _toRemoteBranch_. Efectively, pushing _empty_ to remote branch.

Answer (score 32):

Use:

```
git remote prune <remote>
```

Where `<remote>` is a remote source name like *origin* or *upstream*.

Example:  `git remote prune origin`

Comment: for future readers, here's the difference between [`git remote prune`, `git prune`, `git fetch --prune`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20106712/what-are-the-differences-between-git-remote-prune-git-prune-git-fetch-prune).

Answer (score 13):

I've been using

```bash
git fetch -p && git branch -vv | awk '/: gone]/{print $1}' | xargs git branch -D
```

to delete the local branches pointing to merged branches.

Comment: This is the right answer to the question asked.