# fetch from origin with deleted remote branches?

Tags: git, git-fetch

When I do `git fetch origin` and origin has a deleted branch, it doesn't seem to update it in my repository. When I do `git branch -r` it still shows `origin/DELETED_BRANCH`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [git remote branch deleted but still appears in 'branch -a'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094293/git-remote-branch-deleted-but-still-appears-in-branch-a)

Answer (score 1151, accepted):

You need to do the following

```
git fetch -p
```

The `-p` or `--prune` argument will update the local database of remote branches.

Comment: For some reason, your command did not work, but this one did for a non-existent remote branch in my `origin` fork:


`git fetch -p origin`


When I then did

`git branch -r`

the non-existent remote branch no longer showed up.

Comment: @oldfartdeveloper What version are you using? I'm on `git version 1.8.2.1`. Do a `git --version` to find out.

Comment: For completeness: it must be the same as `git remote prune origin` and similar to `git pull --prune` mentioned at http://stackoverflow.com/a/6127884/94687 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/17983126/94687 respectively.

Comment: guys when i do this it says `[deleted] (none) -> origin/ < branch name >` and the branch is still shown on the local repo any idea why ?

Comment: I get a message saying my branches have been deleted, but running `git branch` still shows the branches which were supposedly deleted.

Comment: This will only remove the tracking setup between the local branch and it's remote counterpart. It is explained here clearly: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#_pruning
The local branch stays after executing `git fetch -p`, but because the tracking is removed, any `git push` done later won't affect the server's state.

Answer (score 105):

From http://www.gitguys.com/topics/adding-and-removing-remote-branches/

> After someone deletes a branch from a remote repository, git will not
>   automatically delete  the local repository branches when a user does a
>   git pull or git fetch. However, if the user would like to have all
>   tracking branches removed from their local repository that have been
>   deleted in a remote repository, they can type:
>
> git remote prune origin

As a note, the -p param from `git fetch -p` actually means "prune". 

Either way you chose, the non-existing remote branches will be deleted from your local repository.

Comment: I like this since it doesn't fetch anything new.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think this should be the "accepted" answer as you give some background information on the commands.

Answer (score 40):

You need to do the following

```
git fetch -p
```

in order to synchronize your branch list. The [git manual](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html) says

> `-p`, `--prune`
>   After fetching, remove any remote-tracking references that no longer exist on the remote. Tags are not subject to pruning if they are fetched only because of the default tag auto-following or due to a `--tags` option. However, if tags are fetched due to an explicit refspec (either on the command line or in the remote configuration, for example if the remote was cloned with the `--mirror` option), then they are also subject to pruning.

I personally like to use `git fetch origin -p --progress` because it shows a progress indicator.

Answer (score 23):

This worked for me.

```
git remote update --prune
```

Answer (score 10):

Regarding `git fetch -p`, its behavior changed in Git 1.9, and only Git 2.9.x/2.10 reflects that.

See [commit 9e70233](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9e70233a17f158f499c60ff82c20c7646fde66e8) (13 Jun 2016) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 1c22105](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1c22105f2ce6795035f4d030325127dab9736caa), 06 Jul 2016)</sup>

> ### `fetch`: document that pruning happens *before* fetching
>
> This was changed in [10a6cc8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/10a6cc8890ec1e5459c05ddeb28a671acdc37d60) (`fetch --prune`: Run prune before fetching, 2014-01-02), but it seems that nobody in that discussion realized we were advertising the "after" explicitly.

So the documentation now states:

> ***Before*** fetching, remove any remote-tracking references that no longer exist on the remote

That is because:

> When we have a remote-tracking branch named "`frotz/nitfol`" from a previous fetch, and the upstream now has a branch named "`frotz`", fetch would fail to remove "`frotz/nitfol`" with a "`git fetch --prune`" from the upstream. git would inform the user to use "`git remote prune`" to fix the problem.
>
> Change the way "`fetch --prune`" works by moving the pruning operation before the fetching operation. This way, instead of warning the user of a conflict, it automatically fixes it.

Answer (score 5):

For `git` and `Apple git` newer than version `2.x` this worked for me:

```
git remote prune origin
```

Answer (score 2):

If `git fetch -p origin` does not work for some reason (like because the origin repo no longer exists or you are unable to reach it), another solution is to remove the information which is stored locally on that branch by doing from the root of the repo:

```
rm .git/refs/remotes/origin/DELETED_BRANCH
```

or if it is stored in the file `.git/packed-refs` by deleting the corresponding line which is like

```
7a9930974b02a3b31cb2ebd17df6667514962685 refs/remotes/origin/DELETED_BRANCH
```

Answer (score 0):

This is now a configuration value in .gitconfig

[fetch]
prune = true

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-fetchprune