# How do I delete all Git branches which have been merged?

Tags: git, version-control, branch, feature-branch

How do I delete branches which have already been merged? Can I delete them all at once, instead of deleting each branch one-by-one?

Comment: To be slightly more specific `git branch -D` deletes any branch whether it as been merged or not.

Comment: You can also do this directly from GitHub, if you go to the 'branches' section of your repo (e.g. https://github.com/<username>/<repo_name>/branches). There should be a list of all your branches, with a red trashcan icon on the side which will delete the selected branch. Much faster than doing it in the terminal! Will also show how far ahead/behind `master` each branch is. However, your local client will still list the old branches if you run `git branch -a`; use `git fetch --prune` to remove them (as per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17029936/5359531) ).

Comment: Script to do this locally or remotely - with safety checks and pre-configured "safe branches": https://github.com/fatso83/dotfiles/tree/master/utils/scripts#git-delete-merged `git delete-merged --doit origin` or `git delete-merged --doit --local`

Comment: You could also use [this app](https://probot.github.io/apps/delete-merged-branch/) to auto delete merged branches.

Comment: `rm -fr work && git clone http://example.com/work.git` over the years has become the easiest way to get out of a pickle with git.

Comment: More recent question [How can I delete all git branches which have been “Squash and Merge” via GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43489303/873282), because "squashing and merging" was not available when this question was asked.

Comment: ```git branch -a --merged| egrep -v "(^\*|master|main|dev)" | sed 's/remotes\/origin\///g' | xargs git push --delete origin``` Thanks, tried this to remove remote branches

Comment: There is an alias already if you're using oh-my-zsh git plugin: `gbda`

Answer (score 3979, accepted):

NOTE: You can add other branches to exclude like master and dev if your workflow has those as a possible ancestor. Usually I branch off of a "sprint-start" tag and master, dev and qa are not ancestors.

---

First, list locally-tracking branches that were merged in remote (consider using `-r` flag to list all remote-tracking branches).

```
git branch --merged
```

You might see few branches you don't want to remove. We can add few arguments to skip important branches that we don't want to delete like master or a develop. The following command will skip master branch and anything that has dev in it.

```
git branch --merged| grep -Ev "(^\*|master|main|dev)"
```

If you want to skip, you can add it to the egrep command like the following. The branch `skip_branch_name` will not be deleted.

```
git branch --merged| grep -Ev "(^\*|master|main|dev|skip_branch_name)"
```

To delete all local branches that are already merged into the currently checked out branch:

```
git branch --merged | grep -Ev "(^\*|master|main|dev)" | xargs git branch -d
```

You can see that master and dev are excluded in case they are an ancestor.

---

You can delete a merged local branch with:

```
git branch -d branchname
```

If it's not merged, use:

```
git branch -D branchname
```

To delete it from the remote use:

```
git push --delete origin branchname

git push origin :branchname    # for really old git
```

Once you delete the branch from the remote, you can prune to get rid of remote tracking branches with:

```
git remote prune origin
```

or prune individual remote tracking branches, as the other answer suggests, with:

```
git branch -dr branchname
```

Comment: yeah, I know how delete a branch. But I have 100 branches and 50 of them already merged to the master and another 50 is not merget yet. So I want to delete the branches which are merged to the master. So I'm asking here, how delete them faster than delete one by one.

Comment: git checkout master; for branch in $(git branch --raw); do git branch --contains $branch && git branch -d $branch; done

Comment: git branch --merged | sed 's/\\*/ /'  | xargs -n 1 git branch -d    --Gets rid of that pesky asteryx

Comment: WARNING: If you just created a branch it will also delete that one. Make sure to not have a newly created branch in the list before you run the top most command.

Comment: I'd like to see an example on how to do this with git push --delete as the output of the grep is something like origin/feature/branch, but the push command doesn't want the origin/ prefix.

Comment: So, what I see as a good solution is the following if you want to remove merged branches from both your remote and your local
`git branch --merged | grep -v "\*" | xargs -n 1 git push --delete origin`
`git branch --merged | grep -v "\*" | xargs -n 1 git branch -d`

Comment: Yeah I was about the use the same...I think there should be a warning at the top of answer

Comment: OPPOSITE OF WARNING: reflog will save your bacon. So don't worry.

Comment: Keep in mind that the first command only deletes local branches, so it isn't as 'dangerous' as some have pointed out.

Comment: OPPOSITE OF OPPOSITE OF WARNING: (why are we shouting???) - annoying to get 'pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git...' and have to `git checkout master origin/master` at some later point. `git branch --merged | grep -E -v "\*|master" | xargs -n 1 git branch -d` FTW

Comment: reflog won't save your bacon.  deleting a branch deletes its reflog.  You can get the most recent branch tip back, but you can no longer say `master@{1}` or `master@{yesterday noon}`

Comment: Add `--no-color` if you use color by default. Example:
```git branch --merged develop --no-color | cat | grep -v "\* develop" | xargs -n 1 git branch -d```

Comment: PowerShell variant, so that I could find it here next time I googled the answer: `git branch --merged | %{$_.trim()}  | ?{$_ -notmatch 'develop' -and $_ -notmatch 'master'} | %{git branch -d $_}`

Comment: This produces an error `fatal: branch name required` if you have no branches that should be deleted.  To avoid that you can pass `-r` to `xargs` so it won't run `git branch -d` if the stdin is empty.  (This a GNU xargs extension, according to the man page).

Comment: I created [a bash function](https://github.com/jessepinho/dotfiles/blob/15a8239dcb4aad2d72e641650e541555b79201e8/.bash_profile#L61-L68) to prune both merged branches and remote merged branches, if this helps anyone.

Comment: PowerShell variant (based on @vorou's) for deleting remote branches: 
`git branch -r --merged | %{$_.trim()} | ?{$_ -match '/bug/' -or $_ -match '/feature/'} | %{$_ -replace 'origin/',''} | %{git push --delete origin $_}`

Comment: Thanks!  I just added an `alias` to my `~/.profile`!  Very helpful answer!

Comment: @danielricecodes How did you add an alias? `clean-branches = !git branch --merged | egrep -v "(^\*|master|dev)" | xargs git branch -d` doesn't work for me (bad config file error)

Comment: @Akarienta - `alias git-branch-clean="git branch --merged | egrep -v \"(^\*|master|dev|staging|production)\" | xargs git branch -d"`

Comment: `git branch --merged | egrep -v "(^\*|master|dev)" | xargs -I % echo 'git branch -d % ; git push --delete freephile % ;'`
Using *echo* helps you look before you leap.  % is the replacement string in xargs.  Change 'echo' to 'sh -c' to execute.  Does both local and remote prunes.

Comment: Warning: `git branch --merged` without further arguments will show all branches which are merged into the current checkedout branch. You should always use something like `git branch --merged origin/master`

Comment: Full command, better then pipe because it will use one transaction: `git push origin --delete $(git branch -r --merged origin/master |  grep origin | egrep -v '>|master|develop' | cut -d/ -f2-)`

Comment: If you have ui colours set in git, you may need to disable them temporarily to avoid encoding errors - just set `ui = never` under the `[color]` section in .gitconfig

Comment: I had to add the `--no-color` switch before `--merged`: `git branch --no-color --merged | egrep -v "(^\*|master|dev)" | xargs git branch -d`

Comment: It would be better if the regexp explicitly marked the end of line character, i.e. `git branch --merged | egrep -v "(^\*|master)$"`.

Comment: The egrep pattern excludes all branches containing master, not just master itself,  fix by using `egrep -v "^(\* .*| *master| *dev)$"`

Comment: I think it's worth noting that branches that have been cherry-picked to the current branch wont show as merged using this solution. Even though OP said merged, many people only care for merged branches to know whether they can safely delete a branch so as to not lose any data. Even branches not returned by this solution, could be safely removed if `git log upstream...currentBranch --cherry-pick --right-only` doesn't return anything

Comment: I use the following command as my daily basis

```bash
git branch --merged | egrep -v "(^\*|master|dev)" | xargs git branch -d
```
But I was tired to run it every time so I added an alias in my .bash_profile.
I have an article about how to do it [here](https://www.boobo94.xyz/tutorials/cleanup-merged-branches-git/)

Comment: Combining with kuboons answer below to replicate the branch deletion (excluding master and dev) on remote: ```git branch -r --merged | egrep -v "(^\*|master|dev)" | sed 's/origin\//:/' | xargs -n 1 git push origin``` - disclaimer: My bash skills aren't great, so check you are happy with what this does before running. Looked to work for me.

Comment: My 2 cents: In case you'd want to delete merged branches on remote, while excluding `master` and/or `dev`, you will need to trim some of the output since `git push` does not work with paths. The command that I've been using lately:
`git branch -r | egrep -v "^\*|master|dev" | cut -d '/' -f 2 | xargs git push --delete origin`

Comment: Naturally, this won't work on Windows since it uses `egrep`...

Comment: Thnx! I made a bash one-liner of it `for i in \`git branch --merged| egrep -v "(^\*|master|dev)"\`; do git branch -d ${i}; done;`

Comment: `git branch -r --merged | grep -v master | sed 's/origin\//:refs\/heads\//' | xargs -n 1 git push origin`

Comment: If you are like me and accumulate a lot of local branches, some completed by other devs. The following set of commands work to rebase everything onto the head of their tracking branches -- aborting any with conflicts before `-d` deleting

`git fetch origin; git branch | grep -v -E "(^\*|master|staging|beta)" | xargs -I % sh -c "git checkout % && (git rebase || git rebase --abort); git branch | grep -v -E "(^\*|master|staging|beta)" | xargs -L 1 git branch -d`

Comment: This is not a great answer you can copy-paste a command from. What fetching is required should be part of it.

Answer (score 590):

To delete all branches on remote that are already merged:

```
git branch -r --merged | grep -v master | sed 's/origin\//:/' | xargs -n 1 git push origin
```

In more recent versions of Git

```
git branch -r --merged | grep -v master | sed 's/origin\///' | xargs -n 1 git push --delete origin
```

**UPDATE (by @oliver; since does not fit in comment, but enough answers already)**: if you are on branch ABC then ABC will appear in the results of `git branch -r --merged` because the branch is not specified, so branch defaults to current branch, and a branch always qualifies as merged to itself (because there are no differences between a branch and itself!).

So either specify the branch:

```
git branch -r --merged master | grep -v master ...
```

OR first checkout master:

```
git checkout master | git branch -r --merged | grep -v ...
```

Comment: Best answer by far. Just a note, my master branch is named `dev` so I had to change that

Comment: I had to add `| grep origin` after `grep -v master` to prevent pushing branches of other remotes to origin. Highly recommending testing the output beforehand, using `git branch -r --merged | grep -v master | grep origin | sed 's/origin\//:/' | xargs -n 1 echo`

Comment: I slightly modified to exclude `develop` branch as well. `git branch -r --merged | grep -v master | grep -v develop | sed 's/origin\///' | xargs -n 1 git push --delete origin`. Now this turned out to be my alias.

Comment: What made this the best answer I've read, is the `-r` argument, which I've not seen mentioned anywhere else. It's taken for granted that only local branches are worth doing some housekeeping on. But remotes are full of garbage too.

Comment: Apart from `| grep origin` you can also add `--no-verify` at the end to skip git pre-push hook

Comment: Caution - just realized: this will obviously find branches merged to *current branch*, not master, so if you are on `myFeatureBranch` it will wipe `origin/myFeatureBranch`. Probably it's best to `git checkout master` first.

Comment: This works great. Except, it doesn't delete branches with the word 'master' in their name. (e.g. master-TRIAG-873). I've tried the solution below (`grep -v '^  master$'`), but that still includes the actual master branch when I try it.

Comment: @kuboon - I really think your answer should be added to Adam's answer as an edit, because both your answer and his pertain to the question.  I would do it myself, but most of my edits to date have been rejected and it should be to your credit anyway.

Comment: @kuboon  Branch is deleting but im getting error ->  remote: fatal: bad object 0000000000000000 remote: 
remote: Syntax checker hook is malfunctioning - can't execute git ls-tree. Failing gracefully and allowing this push.
remote: fatal: bad object 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
remote: fatal: Invalid revision range ed2b135a69b9f3594b7631b70fed6b82a8dc1ad4..0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
remote: fatal: git cat-file 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000: bad file
To git@git.cfteam.in:root/myproj.git
 - [deleted]         shield_square_removal

Comment: WARNING: This also closes open pull requests.

Comment: `git branch -r --merged | grep -v master | grep -v develop | sed 's/origin\///' | xargs -n 1 git push --delete origin` WARNING: This command will delete and close open pull requests.

Comment: You can eliminate the `sed` step by using the  `--format` to include only the needed part of the ref `git branch --format "%(refname:lstrip=3)" --remotes --merged`
The available field names are documented [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#_field_names). They are *not* the same as the format for other git sub commands.

Comment: In the last command, it should be `git checkout master &&`, not `git checkout master |`.

Comment: Is it possible to add a git alias for this?

Comment: @DarVar, yes. `drm = !git checkout master && git branch -r --merged | grep -v master | sed \"s/origin\\///\" | xargs -n 1 git push --delete origin` should work as an alias in `.gitconfig`

Comment: @scones, can you clarify your warning about closing open pull requests ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65444886/how-clean-up-merged-git-branches-can-delete-pull-requests

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim sure. if you execute the commands, your pull requests will be closed. not merged tho.

Comment: Changing the `-n 1` to a higher value deletes more branches at once

Comment: I like this, but had to change it a bit to work with multiple remotes: `git branch -r --merged | sed '/main/d' | sed 's/\//\n/' | cat | xargs -L2 bash -c 'git push --delete $0 $1'`

Answer (score 291):

Just extending Adam's answer a little bit:

Add this to your Git configuration by running `git config -e --global`

```
[alias]
    cleanup = "!git branch --merged | grep  -v '\\*\\|master\\|develop' | xargs -n 1 -r git branch -d"
```

And then you can delete all the local merged branches doing a simple `git cleanup`.

Comment: shouldn't the first command be: `git branch --merged master` since you want to look at what has been merged into master, not currently checked out branch?

Comment: @JoePhilllips Some people has the main branch not master but instead `develop` or `dev` and in that case the command will fail with `fatal: malformed object name` it's better to have a generic command and you have the responsibility to run it

Comment: @SKandeel Yes I agree but most people can figure out to change that for their particular case. It's a little odd to have to be sitting on a certain branch in order for cleanup to work

Comment: @JoePhilllips the point of this answer is to package up Adam's answer (the top answer for this question) in helpful git alias. Adam's answer doesn't have what you are suggesting and so many people have found that useful so I would be inclined not to change mine. I would recommend opening the discussion on Adam's answer if you feel strongly about it

Comment: @Adam's answer was updated/simplified a little bit. Just thought you might want to know in case you want to update your answer as well because *"the point of this answer is to package up Adam's answer"*.

Comment: @SKandeel it might also be interesting to note that on another [one of Adam's very similar answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8236216/4233593), he does qualify it with `master`

Comment: Adding `-r` to `xargs` will prevent unnecessary errors (`branch name required`) when running this alias multiple times or when there is no branch left to be deleted. My alias looks like this:
`cleanup = "!git branch --merged | grep -v -P '^\\*|master|develop' | xargs -n1 -r git branch -d"`

Comment: Is that going to be the case for all versions of xargs? I know there are some differences between linux and mac on this and I want to make sure this works for all cases. 

Also I've never come across this issue before :/ example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAY2H.png

Comment: `nuke = "!sh -c \"git branch --merged master | grep -v -P '\\*|master' | xargs -n1 -r git branch -D\""` For windows users, this is what ended up finally working for me: Thanks @spezifanta for getting me almost all the way there.

Comment: Current command doesn't filter out master and develop branches

Comment: @AndriyF. what platform are you using? the current command works well for me and does filter out master and develop :)

Comment: @real_ate Linux OpensSuse git 2.16.4 grep 3.1

Comment: This uses hardcoded branch names, shameless selfplug, I added an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72118951/258418) which avoids this problem, and where the alias can be created from the command line rather than be editing the config file (simple copy paste).

Answer (score 144):

You'll want to exclude the `master`, `main` & `develop` branches from those commands.

Local git clear:

```
git branch --merged | grep -v '\*\|master\|main\|develop' | xargs -n 1 git branch -d
```

Remote git clear:

```
git branch -r --merged | grep -v '\*\|master\|main\|develop' | sed 's/origin\///' | xargs -n 1 git push --delete origin
```

Sync local registry of remote branches:

```
git fetch -p
```

Comment: +1 for the remote version as well (but less needed as we have remote --prune). Also worth noting that thoose won't work with older git version

Comment: ``git config --global --add fetch.prune true`` to prune automatically on fetch or pull.

Comment: Mind you, prune is not the same as the remote clear. The remote clear actually deletes the remote branches that are fully merged with your current branch. Prune only cleans up your local registry of remote branches that are already deleted.

Comment: The word fully is a bit misleading, as a branch will be considered merged, when it was merged before, but has new commits after the merge, which were not merged.

Comment: To delete all the origin remotes in one call, I used this: `git branch -r --merged | grep -v '\*\|master\|develop' | grep '^\s*origin/' | sed 's/origin\///' | tr "\n" " " | xargs git push --delete origin`

Comment: Note that you should be on the fully updated master branch when you run the remote one, otherwise you risk deleting the branch you're currently on from remote and losing some pull requests and such.

Comment: Uhmm... How would that happen? If master is not updated, the branches are not merged in, and thus do not get removed.

Comment: I noticed that this will also delete local branches that have not been pushed!  I had a local `poc-stuff` branch where I would try out stuff.  When I ran this command, that got deleted...

Answer (score 93):

This also works to delete all merged branches except master.

```
git branch --merged | grep -v '^* master$' | grep -v '^  master$' | grep -v '^* main$' | grep -v '^  main$' | xargs git branch -d
```

Edit: Also ignoring main branch as it's being used these days

Comment: Now it won't delete any branch with `master` in it. Try `grep -v ^master$` for the middle.

Comment: I'd also let ```| grep -v '^\*'``` to avoid deletting current branch if you are **not on master**

Comment: This is great, thanks! One caveat for anyone using this: note that there are two spaces in `grep -v '^  master$'`. If you type it in yourself and miss one, you'll delete `master` if you're not on it.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl your edit breaks the command and you should revert it. The two spaces are necessary, since `git branch` will list each branch name on a new line with two spaces to the left if it is not the currently checked out branch. You have essentially guaranteed that anyone who runs this command will delete their master branch unless it is the currently checked out branch.

Comment: this is 2023, we need to exclude main branch too. it's the default for too many repos :)

Answer (score 88):

For those of you that are on Windows and prefer PowerShell scripts, here is one that deletes local merged branches:

```
function Remove-MergedBranches
{
  git branch --merged |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() } |
    Where-Object { $_ -NotMatch "^\*" } |
    Where-Object { -not ( $_ -Like "*master" -or $_ -Like "*main" ) } |
    ForEach-Object { git branch -d $_ }
}
```

Or the short version:

```
git branch --merged | %{$_.trim()}  | ?{$_ -notmatch 'dev' -and $_ -notmatch 'master' -and $_ -notmatch 'main'} | %{git branch -d $_.trim()}
```

Comment: For curiosity sake, this can be shortened to 
`git branch --merged | ?{-not ($_ -like "*master")} | %{git branch -d $_.trim()}`

Comment: @IainBallard Sure, I could have used aliases. That is not recommended when you want to maximize readability. https://github.com/darkoperator/PSStyleGuide/blob/master/English.md

Comment: sure. I found your answer very helpful :-) However sometimes the long-form powershell syntax gets in the way of what's going on in the blocks. But primarily, I was putting forward something you might copy/paste or type as a one-off. Thanks again.

Comment: Here's a one-liner for Windows cmd shell that preserves master and your current branch: `for /f "usebackq" %B in (``git branch --merged^|findstr /v /c:"* " /c:"master"``) do @git branch -d %B` (sigh, replace double-backquotes with single, I'm not sure how to format a literal that contains backquotes)

Answer (score 68):

I've used Adam's answer for years now. That said, that there are some cases where it wasn't behaving as I expected:

1. branches that *contained* the word "master" were ignored, e.g. "notmaster" or "masterful", rather than only the master branch
2. branches that *contained* the word "dev" were ignored, e.g. "dev-test", rather than only the dev branch
3. deleting branches that are reachable from the HEAD of the *current* branch (that is, not necessarily master)
4. in detached HEAD state, deleting *every* branch reachable from the current commit

1 & 2 were straightforward to address, with just a change to the regex.
3 depends on the context of what you want (i.e. only delete branches that haven't been merged into master or against your current branch).
4 has the potential to be disastrous (although recoverable with `git reflog`), if you unintentionally ran this in detached HEAD state.

Finally, I wanted this to all be in a one-liner that didn't require a separate (Bash|Ruby|Python) script.

### TL;DR

Create a git alias "sweep" that accepts an optional `-f` flag:

```
git config --global alias.sweep '!git branch --merged $([[ $1 != "-f" ]] \
&& git rev-parse master) | egrep -v "(^\*|^\s*(master|develop)$)" \
| xargs git branch -d'
```

and invoke it with:

```
git sweep
```

or:

```
git sweep -f
```

## The long, detailed answer

It was easiest for me to create an example git repo with some branches and commits to test the correct behavior:

#### Create a new git repo with a single commit

```
mkdir sweep-test && cd sweep-test && git init
echo "hello" > hello
git add . && git commit -am "initial commit"
```

#### Create some new branches

```
git branch foo && git branch bar && git branch develop && git branch notmaster && git branch masterful
git branch --list
```

> ```
>   bar
>   develop
>   foo
> * master
>   masterful
>   notmaster
> ```

#### Desired behavior: select all merged branches except: master, develop or *current*

The original regex misses the branches "masterful" and "notmaster" :

```
git checkout foo
git branch --merged | egrep -v "(^\*|master|dev)"
```

> ```
>   bar
> ```

With the updated regex (which now excludes "develop" rather than "dev"):

```
git branch --merged | egrep -v "(^\*|^\s*(master|develop)$)"
```

> ```
> bar
> masterful
> notmaster
> ```

#### Switch to branch foo, make a new commit, then checkout a new branch, foobar, based on foo:

```
echo "foo" > foo
git add . && git commit -am "foo"
git checkout -b foobar
echo "foobar" > foobar
git add . && git commit -am "foobar"
```

My current branch is foobar, and if I re-run the above command to list the branches I want to delete, the branch "foo" is included even though it hasn't been merged into master:

```
git branch --merged | egrep -v "(^\*|^\s*(master|develop)$)"
```

> ```
>   bar
>   foo
>   masterful
>   notmaster
> ```

However, if I run the same command on master, the branch "foo" is not included:

```
git checkout master && git branch --merged | egrep -v "(^\*|^\s*(master|develop)$)"
```

> ```
>   bar
>   masterful
>   notmaster
> ```

And this is simply because `git branch --merged` defaults to the HEAD of the current branch if not otherwise specified. At least for my workflow, I don't want to delete local branches unless they've been merged to master, so I prefer the following variant [using git rev-parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798862/what-does-git-rev-parse-do):

```
git checkout foobar
git branch --merged $(git rev-parse master) | egrep -v "(^\*|^\s*(master|develop)$)"
```

> ```
>   bar
>   masterful
>   notmaster
> ```

#### Detached HEAD state

Relying on the default behavior of `git branch --merged` has even more significant consequences in detached HEAD state:

```
git checkout foobar
git checkout HEAD~0
git branch --merged | egrep -v "(^\*|^\s*(master|develop)$)"
```

> ```
>   bar
>   foo
>   foobar
>   masterful
>   notmaster
> ```

This would have deleted the branch I was just on, "foobar" along with "foo", which is almost certainly not the desired outcome.
With our revised command, however:

```
git branch --merged $(git rev-parse master) | egrep -v "(^\*|^\s*(master|develop)$)"
```

> ```
>   bar
>   masterful
>   notmaster
> ```

#### One line, including the actual delete

```
git branch --merged $(git rev-parse master) | egrep -v "(^\*|^\s*(master|develop)$)" | xargs git branch -d
```

#### All wrapped up into a git alias "sweep":

```
git config --global alias.sweep '!git branch --merged $([[ $1 != "-f" ]] \
&& git rev-parse master) | egrep -v "(^\*|^\s*(master|develop)$)" \
| xargs git branch -d'
```

The alias accepts an optional `-f` flag. The default behavior is to only delete branches that have been merged into master, but the `-f` flag will delete branches that have been merged into the current branch.

```
git sweep
```

> ```
> Deleted branch bar (was 9a56952).
> Deleted branch masterful (was 9a56952).
> Deleted branch notmaster (was 9a56952).
> ```

```
git sweep -f
```

> ```
> Deleted branch foo (was 2cea1ab).
> ```

Comment: Why do you need to create a function? Isn't `git config` atomic?

Comment: To deal with the optional '-f' argument (if I understand your question correctly)

Comment: but how does it help? I mean the start of the expression, `!f(){ git branch ...`. It's a function declaration, right? Why not start directly with `git branch ...` ?

Comment: You're absolutely right. Edited my answer accordingly. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: Would the following not do the same as the non-force-mode?

`git checkout master && git branch -d \`git branch --merged\` && git checkout -`

Except that it would delete `develop`, but might be a simpler approach.

Comment: @GuidoBouman yes, but with notable caveats: one you already mentioned (deleting `develop`); other caveats would be related to switching back and forth between branches, e.g.: uncommitted changes need to be handled before switching branches; depending on what you have going on in other tools (editors, profiler, running app server from your branch, etc.) switching branches might disrupt your flow.

Answer (score 31):

So many bad answers here. This is what you probably want:

```
git branch --delete $(git branch --merged master --no-contains master --format='%(refname:short)')
```

This selects all local branches that have been merged into `master` (including `master`), *and* that aren't descendent of `master` (which excludes `master` itself). The `--format` is necessary because by default Git prints asterisks for the currently checked out branches. You might be able to do this with `git for-each-ref` too but it seems more complicated (it lists remote branches too).

You *don't* want:

- `git branch --merged` (without `master`): This will list branches that have been "merged" into your *currently checked out commit* (i.e. `HEAD`), which is probably unexpected and not what you want.
- `| grep -v master`: There's no need for this; you can just use `--no-contains`.
- `| xargs`: Again, no need. `git branch --delete` can delete more than one branch.

---

Update: I've been using this for a while and it works pretty well. There are two minor flaws:

1. If there are no branches to delete it will give you an error. That's fine for interactive use IMO. You shouldn't be using this in a script anyway since it's Bash and Bash *should not be used for scripting*.
2. It won't delete branches that point to the same commit as `master`. I have [a tool](https://github.com/Timmmm/autorebase) that automatically rebases all my branches, and for ones that have been merged it can leave them in this state. This may not matter to you.

Comment: Not tested but this looks clean (no pipes with grep and misc.). Thanks.

Comment: This does not work if there are no branches other than master

Comment: Yeah it gives you an error, but it's fairly benign because there was nothing to do anyway.

Comment: Much cleaner of a solution, I just think it wasn't necessary to outright call the other solutions as "so many bad answers here".

Comment: 13 years later and still useful. I've been looking for a solution that works everywhere for a long time. This is it! works on Windows where you don't have egrep or xargs. It can easily be put into .gitconfig

Comment: re | xargs: Again, no need. git branch --delete can delete more than one branch.    xargs resolves the issues of command line length being too big, not the issue of multiple args.  if your $(..) produces a string too long for the CLI this command will bork, pipe it to xargs and CLI length is never too long, n.b. it does not send them one by one it just makes sure cli is not too big

Comment: The maximum command line length is usually at least 100k characters (on my system it's 2 million). It's not going to be an issue unless you're doing something that is unlikely to work with `xargs` either.

Answer (score 25):

Using Git version 2.5.0:

```
git branch -d `git branch --merged`
```

Comment: This can delete the `master` branch btw!

Comment: True. I only use it when I'm sure I'm on `master`.

Comment: `git branch -d $(git branch --merged | grep -v master)`

Comment: This is dangerous if you have a flow, imagine you have master <- stage <- dev.
Still easiest solution imo

Comment: Does this delete all branches merged by the current user or by any user?

Answer (score 22):

If you're on Windows you can use Windows Powershell or Powershell 7 with [Out-GridView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-gridview?view=powershell-5.1) to have a nice list of branches and select with mouse which one you want to delete:

```
git branch --format "%(refname:short)" --merged  | Out-GridView -PassThru | % { git branch -d $_ }
```

[image]
after clicking OK Powershell will pass this branches names to `git branch -d` command and delete them
[image]

Answer (score 19):

You can add the commit to the --merged option.
This way you can make sure only to remove branches which are merged into i.e. the origin/master

Following command will remove merged branches from your origin.

```
git branch -r --merged origin/master | grep -v "^.*master" | sed s:origin/:: |xargs -n 1 git push origin --delete
```

You can test which branches will be removed replacing the git push origin --delete with echo

```
git branch -r --merged origin/master | grep -v "^.*master" | sed s:origin/:: |xargs -n 1 echo
```

Comment: I like the test option

Answer (score 19):

My favorite and simple script:

```
git branch --merged | grep -E -v "(master|main|develop|other)" | xargs git branch -d
```

Comment: delete all but the selected ones
    `git branch | grep -E -v "(master|develop|other)" | xargs git branch -D`

Comment: Update to support 'main' branch which is often the default branch now days: 

`git branch --merged | grep -E -v "(master|main|develop|other)" | xargs git branch -d`

Comment: The best for me too :)

Answer (score 13):

I use the following Ruby script to delete my already merged local and remote branches. If I'm doing it for a repository with multiple remotes and only want to delete from one, I just add a select statement to the remotes list to only get the remotes I want.

```ruby
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

current_branch = `git symbolic-ref --short HEAD`.chomp
if current_branch != "master"
  if $?.exitstatus == 0
    puts "WARNING: You are on branch #{current_branch}, NOT master."
  else
    puts "WARNING: You are not on a branch"
  end
  puts
end

puts "Fetching merged branches..."
remote_branches= `git branch -r --merged`.
  split("\n").
  map(&:strip).
  reject {|b| b =~ /\/(#{current_branch}|master)/}

local_branches= `git branch --merged`.
  gsub(/^\* /, '').
  split("\n").
  map(&:strip).
  reject {|b| b =~ /(#{current_branch}|master)/}

if remote_branches.empty? && local_branches.empty?
  puts "No existing branches have been merged into #{current_branch}."
else
  puts "This will remove the following branches:"
  puts remote_branches.join("\n")
  puts local_branches.join("\n")
  puts "Proceed?"
  if gets =~ /^y/i
    remote_branches.each do |b|
      remote, branch = b.split(/\//)
      `git push #{remote} :#{branch}`
    end

    # Remove local branches
    `git branch -d #{local_branches.join(' ')}`
  else
    puts "No branches removed."
  end
end
```

Comment: @mmrobins You have an extra `\/` at the beginning of the reject statement for the `remote_branches` line. Is that a typo or does it serve a purpose?

Comment: @mmrobins, oh never mind I see the `b.split(/\//)` line now

Comment: If you want to do basically this but via vanilla bash rather than ruby: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37999948/430128

Answer (score 13):

#### How to delete merged branches in PowerShell console

```
git branch --merged | %{git branch -d $_.Trim()}
```

If you want to exclude **master** or any other branch names, you can pipe with PowerShell Select-String like this and pass the result to `git branch -d`:

```
git branch -d $(git branch --merged | Select-String -NotMatch "master" | %{$_.ToString().Trim()})
```

Comment: Higher answers are suggesting filtering master or other branches. For those looking to do that in powershell:

    git branch --merged | findstr /v "master" | %{git branch -d $_.trim()}

Comment: @tredzko Good point. FTR the higher answer is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127328/how-can-i-delete-all-git-branches-which-have-been-merged#comment41181501_24143004 - you could repost your comment with that linked and I'd then delete this

Comment: it also tries to delete `* master` :)

Answer (score 13):

*Note*: I am not happy with previous answers, (not working on all systems, not working on remote, not specifying the --merged branch, not filtering exactly). So, I add my own answer.

There are two main cases:

**Local**

You want to *delete local branches* that are *already merged to another local branch*. During the deletion, you want to keep some important branches, like master, develop, etc.

```
git branch --format "%(refname:short)" --merged master | grep -E -v '^master$|^feature/develop$' | xargs -n 1 git branch -d
```

*Notes*:

- `git branch output --format` ".." is to strip whitespaces and allow exact grep matching
- `grep -E` is used *instead of* `egrep`, so it works also in systems without egrep (i.e.: git for windows).
- `grep -E -v '^master$|^feature/develop$'` is to specify local branches that I don't want to delete
- `xargs -n 1 git branch -d`: perform the deletion of local branches (it won't work for remote ones)
- *of course* you get an error if you try deleting the branch currently checked-out. So, I suggest to switch to master beforehand.

**Remote**

You want to *delete remote branches* that are *already merged to another remote branch*. During the deletion, you want to keep some important branches, like HEAD, master, releases, etc.

```
git branch -r --format "%(refname:short)" --merged origin/master | grep -E -v '^*HEAD$|^*/master$|^*release' | cut -d/ -f2- | xargs -n 1 git push --delete origin
```

*Notes*:

- for remote, we use the `-r` option and provide the *full branch name*: `origin/master`
- `grep -E -v '^*HEAD$|^*/master$|^*release'` is to match the remote branches that we don't want to delete.
- `cut -d/ -f2-` : remove the unneeded 'origin/' prefix that otherwise is printed out by the `git branch` command.
- `xargs -n 1 git push --delete origin` : perform the deletion of remote branches.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `gbda` alias if you're using [OhMyZSH](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh) with [git plugin](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/git).

Answer (score 11):

I use this:

```
git branch --delete $(git branch --format '%(refname:short)' --merged | grep --invert-match 'main\|master\|branch-to-skip')
```

It lists all merged branched in the specified format, then it feeds that list to git branch --delete.

Answer (score 10):

kuboon's answer missed deleting branches which have the word master in the branch name.
The following improves on his answer:

```
git branch -r --merged | grep -v "origin/master$" | sed 's/\s*origin\///' | xargs -n 1 git push --delete origin
```

Of course, it does not delete the "master" branch itself :)

Answer (score 9):

There is no command in Git that will do this for you automatically. But you can write a script that uses Git commands to give you what you need. This could be done in many ways depending on what branching model you are using.

If you need to know if a branch has been merged into master the following command will yield no output if myTopicBranch has been merged (i.e. you can delete it)

```
$ git rev-list master | grep $(git rev-parse myTopicBranch)
```

You could use the Git branch command and parse out all branches in Bash and do a `for` loop over all branches. In this loop you check with above command if you can delete the branch or not.

Answer (score 8):

`git branch --merged | grep -Ev '^(. master|\*)' | xargs -n 1 git branch -d` will delete all local branches except the current checked out branch and/or `master`.

Here's a helpful article for those looking to understand these commands: [Git Clean: Delete Already Merged Branches, by Steven Harman](http://stevenharman.net/git-clean-delete-already-merged-branches).

Answer (score 7):

You can use `git-del-br` [tool](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/git-del-br).

```
git-del-br -a
```

You can install it via `pip` using

```
pip install git-del-br
```

P.S: I am the author of the tool. Any suggestions/feedback are welcome.

Comment: Your answer and tool don't work.  I spend a couple hours on it.  Nothing.

Comment: @SpoiledTechie.com: Can you tell me what problem are you facing exactly? I am using it on a regular basis.

Answer (score 7):

I use a git-flow esque naming scheme, so this works very safely for me:

```
git branch --merged | grep -e "^\s\+\(fix\|feature\)/" | xargs git branch -d
```

It basically looks for merged commits that start with either string `fix/` or `feature/`.

Answer (score 7):

On Windows with [git bash](https://gitforwindows.org/) installed `egrep -v` will not work

```
git branch --merged | grep -E -v "(master|test|dev)" | xargs git branch -d
```

where `grep -E -v` is equivalent of `egrep -v`

Use `-d` to remove already **merged** branches or
`-D` to remove **unmerged** branches

Comment: egrep -v works for me. I'm using gitbash from the gitextensions installer though

Answer (score 7):

The accepted solution is pretty good, but has the one issue that it also deletes local branches that were not yet merged into a remote.

If you look at the output of you will see something like

```
$ git branch --merged master -v
  api_doc                  3a05427 [gone] Start of describing the Java API
  bla                      52e080a Update wording.
  branch-1.0               32f1a72 [maven-release-plugin] prepare release 1.0.1
  initial_proposal         6e59fb0 [gone] Original proposal, converted to AsciiDoc.
  issue_248                be2ba3c Skip unit-for-type checking. This needs more work. (#254)
  master                   be2ba3c Skip unit-for-type checking. This needs more work. (#254)
```

Branches `bla` and `issue_248` are local branches that would be deleted silently.

But you can also see the word `[gone]`, which indicate branches that had been pushed to a remote (which is now gone) and thus denote branches can be deleted.

The original answer can thus be changed to (split into multiline for shorter line length)

```
git branch --merged master -v | \
     grep  "\\[gone\\]" | \
     sed -e 's/^..//' -e 's/\S* .*//' | \
      xargs git branch -d
```

to protect the not yet merged branches.
Also the grepping for master to protect it, is not needed, as this has a remote at origin and does not show up as gone.

Answer (score 6):

Based on some of these answers I made [my own Bash script to do it too](https://gist.github.com/earlonrails/6994990)!

It uses `git branch --merged` and `git branch -d` to delete the branches that have been merged and prompts you for each of the branches before deleting.

```bash
merged_branches () {
    local current_branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
    for branch in $(git branch --merged | cut -c3-)
      do
        echo "Branch $branch is already merged into $current_branch."
        echo "Would you like to delete it? [Y]es/[N]o "
        read REPLY
        if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy] ]]; then
            git branch -d $branch
        fi
    done
}
```

Comment: Branch main is already merged into main...

Answer (score 6):

If you'd like to delete all local branches that are already merged in to the branch that you are currently on, then I've come up with a safe command to do so, based on earlier answers:

```
git branch --merged | grep -v \* | grep -v '^\s*master$' | xargs -t -n 1 git branch -d
```

This command will not affect your current branch or your master branch. It will also tell you what it's doing before it does it, using the -t flag of xargs.

Answer (score 6):

Alias version of [Adam's updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6127884/350761):

```
[alias]
    branch-cleanup = "!git branch --merged | egrep -v \"(^\\*|master|dev)\" | xargs git branch -d #"
```

Also, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39616600/350761) for handy tips on escaping complex aliases.

Answer (score 6):

Below query works for me

```
for branch in  `git branch -r --merged | grep -v '\*\|master\|develop'|awk 'NR > 0 {print$1}'|awk '{gsub(/origin\//, "")}1'`;do git push origin --delete $branch; done
```

and this will filter any given branch in the grep pipe.

Works well over http clone, but not so well for the ssh connection.

Answer (score 5):

Try the following command:

```sh
git branch -d $(git branch --merged | grep -vw $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD))
```

By using `git rev-parse` will get [the current branch name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6245570/55075) in order to exclude it. If you got the error, that means there are no local branches to remove.

To do the same with remote branches (change `origin` with your remote name), try:

```sh
git push origin -vd $(git branch -r --merged | grep -vw $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) | cut -d/ -f2)
```

<sup>In case you've multiple remotes, add `grep origin |` before `cut` to filter only the `origin`.</sup>

If above command fails, try to delete the merged remote-tracking branches first:

```sh
git branch -rd $(git branch -r --merged | grep -vw $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD))
```

Then `git fetch` the remote again and use the previous `git push -vd`command again.

If you're using it often, consider adding as aliases into your `~/.gitconfig` file.

In case you've removed some branches by mistake, use `git reflog` to find the lost commits.

Answer (score 4):

## As of 2018.07

Add this to `[alias]` section of your `~/.gitconfig`:

```
sweep = !"f() { git branch --merged | egrep -v \"(^\\*|master|dev)\" || true | xargs git branch -d; }; f"
```

Now you can just call `git sweep` to perform that needed cleanup.

Comment: For me, calling git sweep only lists the branches that should be cleaned up, but it does not remove them

Answer (score 4):

I've been using the following method to **remove merged local AND remote branches** in one cmd.

I have the following in my `bashrc` file:

```
function rmb {
  current_branch=$(git branch --no-color 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/\1/')
  if [ "$current_branch" != "master" ]; then
    echo "WARNING: You are on branch $current_branch, NOT master."
  fi
  echo "Fetching merged branches..."
  git remote prune origin
  remote_branches=$(git branch -r --merged | grep -v '/master$' | grep -v "/$current_branch$")
  local_branches=$(git branch --merged | grep -v 'master$' | grep -v "$current_branch$")
  if [ -z "$remote_branches" ] && [ -z "$local_branches" ]; then
    echo "No existing branches have been merged into $current_branch."
  else
    echo "This will remove the following branches:"
    if [ -n "$remote_branches" ]; then
      echo "$remote_branches"
    fi
    if [ -n "$local_branches" ]; then
      echo "$local_branches"
    fi
    read -p "Continue? (y/n): " -n 1 choice
    echo
    if [ "$choice" == "y" ] || [ "$choice" == "Y" ]; then
      # Remove remote branches
      git push origin `git branch -r --merged | grep -v '/master$' | grep -v "/$current_branch$" | sed 's/origin\//:/g' | tr -d '\n'`
      # Remove local branches
      git branch -d `git branch --merged | grep -v 'master$' | grep -v "$current_branch$" | sed 's/origin\///g' | tr -d '\n'`
    else
      echo "No branches removed."
    fi
  fi
}
```

original [source](http://rob.by/2013/remove-merged-branches-from-git)

This doesn't delete the master branch, but **removes merged local AND remote branches**. Once you have this in you rc file, just run `rmb`, you're shown a list of merged branches that will be cleaned and asked for confirmation on the action. You can modify the code to not ask for confirmation as well, but it's probably good to keep it in.

Answer (score 3):

Write a script in which Git checks out all the branches that have been merged to master.

Then do `git checkout master`.

Finally, delete the merged branches.

```
for k in $(git branch -ra --merged | egrep -v "(^\*|master)"); do
  branchnew=$(echo $k | sed -e "s/origin\///" | sed -e "s/remotes\///")
  echo branch-name: $branchnew
  git checkout $branchnew
done

git checkout master

for k in $(git branch -ra --merged | egrep -v "(^\*|master)"); do
  branchnew=$(echo $k | sed -e "s/origin\///" | sed -e "s/remotes\///")
  echo branch-name: $branchnew
  git push origin --delete $branchnew
done
```

Answer (score 3):

For me `git branch --merged` doesn't show branches that were merged via GitHub PR. I'm not sure of the reasons, but I use the following line to delete **all local branches that do not have remote tracking branch**:

```
diff <(git branch --format "%(refname:short)") <(git branch -r | grep -v HEAD | cut -d/ -f2-) | grep '<' | cut -c 3- | xargs git branch -D
```

**Explanation:**

- `git branch --format "%(refname:short)"` gives a list of local branches
- `git branch -r | grep -v HEAD | cut -d/ -f2-` gives a list of remote branches, filtering out `HEAD`
- `diff <(...) <(...)` gives a diff of output of two commands inside parentheses
- `grep '<'` filters branches that exist in first list, but not in the second
- `cut -c 3-` gives line starting from 3rd character, thus removing prefix `<`
- `xargs git branch -D` executes `git branch -D` against each branch name

Alternatively, you can avoid `grep -v '<'` like this:

```
diff --old-line-format="%L" --new-line-format="" --unchanged-line-format="" <(git branch --format "%(refname:short)") <(git branch -r | grep -v HEAD | cut -d/ -f2-) | xargs git branch -D
```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid accidentally running the command from any other branch than master I use the following bash script. Otherwise, running `git branch --merged | grep -v "\*" | xargs -n 1 git branch -d` from a branch that has been merged of off master could delete the master branch.

```
#!/bin/bash

branch_name="$(git symbolic-ref HEAD 2>/dev/null)" ||
branch_name="(unnamed branch)"     # detached HEAD
branch_name=${branch_name##refs/heads/}

if [[ $branch_name == 'master' ]]; then
   read -r -p "Are you sure? [y/N] " response
   if [[ $response =~ ^([yY][eE][sS]|[yY])$ ]]; then
       git branch --merged | grep -v "\*" | xargs -n 1 git branch -d
   fi
else
   echo "Refusing to delete branches that are not merged into '$branch_name'. Checkout master first."
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way I found to do it removing only local branches, not remote ones:

`$ git branch --merged | grep -v master | xargs -n 1 git branch -D`

This command will delete only branches already merged in your master one. Be careful if you don't want to delete other branches, such as a `staging`.

Comment: If you using zsh, you can type `gbda` to apply this command

Answer (score 2):

[`git cleanup`](https://github.com/nvie/git-toolbelt#git-cleanup) script from the [git-toolbelt](https://github.com/nvie/git-toolbelt#readme)

> Deletes all branches that have already been merged into master or
> develop. Keeps other branches lying around. Will be most conservative with deletions.
>
> Removes branches both locally and in the origin remote.

Answer (score 1):

To delete local branches that have been merged to master branch I'm using the following alias (`git config -e --global`):

```
cleanup = "!git branch --merged master | grep -v '^*\\|master' | xargs -n 1 git branch -D"
```

I'm using `git branch -D` to avoid `error: The branch 'some-branch' is not fully merged.` messages while my current checkout is different from master branch.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say I have a remote named upstream and an origin (GitHub style, my fork is origin, upstream is upstream).

I don't want to delete ANY masters, HEAD, or anything from the upstream. I also don't want to delete the develop branch as that is our common branch we create PRs from.

List all remote branches, filtered by ones that were merged:

```
git branch -r
```

Remove lines from that list that contain words I know are in branch names I don't want to remove:

```
sed '/develop\|master\|HEAD\|upstream/d'
```

Remove the remote name from the reference name (origin/somebranch becomes somebranch):

```
sed 's/.*\///'
```

Use xargs to call a one-liner:

```
xargs git push --delete origin
```

Pipe it all together you get:

```
git branch -r --merged | sed '/develop\|master\|HEAD\|upstream/d' |  sed 's/.*\///' | xargs git push --delete origin
```

This will leave me with only some branches that I have worked on, but have not merged. You can then remove them one by one as there shouldn't be too many.

Find branches you no longer want:

```
git branch -ar
```

Say you find branch1, branch2, and branch3 you want to delete:

```
git push --delete origin branch1 branch2 branch3
```

Comment: This doesn't work if you have branches named like feature/my-feature as it eats the slash.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ git config --global alias.cleanup
'!git branch --merged origin/master | egrep -v "(^\*|master|staging|dev)" | xargs git branch -d'
```

*(Split into multiple lines for readability)*

Calling "git cleanup" will delete local branches that have already been merged into origin/master. It skips master, staging, and dev because we don't want to delete those in normal circumstances.

Breaking this down, this is what it's doing:

1. `git config --global alias.cleanup`

   - This is creating a global alias called "cleanup" (across all your repos)
2. The `!` at the beginning of the command is saying that we will be using some non-git commands as part of this alias so we need to actually run bash commands here
3. `git branch --merged origin/master`

   - This command returns the list of branch names that have already been merged into `origin/master`
4. `egrep -v "(^\*|master|staging|dev)"`

   - This removes the master, staging, and dev branch from the list of branches that have already been merged. We don't want to remove these branches since they are not features.
5. `xargs git branch -d`

   - This will run the `git branch -d xxxxx` command for each of the unmerged branches. This deletes the local branches one by one.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows you can install [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/install.html) and remove all remote branches using following command:

```
git branch -r --merged | "C:\cygwin64\bin\grep.exe" -v master | "C:\cygwin64\bin\sed.exe" 's/origin\///' | "C:\cygwin64\bin\xargs.exe" -n 1 git push --delete origin
```

Answer (score 1):

Just created python script for that:

```py
import sys
from shutil import which
import logging
from subprocess import check_output, call

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if which("git") is None:
        logger.error("git is not found!")
        sys.exit(-1)

    branches = check_output("git branch -r --merged".split()).strip().decode("utf8").splitlines()
    current = check_output("git branch --show-current".split()).strip().decode("utf8")
    blacklist = ["master", current]

    for b in branches:
        b = b.split("/")[-1]

        if b in blacklist:
            continue
        else:
            if input(f"Do you want to delete branch: '{b}' [y/n]\n").lower() == "y":
                call(f"git branch -D {b}".split())
                call(f"git push --delete origin {b}".split())
```

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr: `git branch --format='%(if:notequals=main)%(refname:short)%(then)%(if:notequals=master)%(refname:short)%(then)%(refname:short)%(end)%(end)' --merged | xargs --max-args=1 --no-run-if-empty echo git branch --delete`, then remove the `echo` if you're happy to actually delete the listed branches.

### Look ma, no tools!

**Git can filter branches without using external tools,** meaning there's a cross-platform, relatively simple way to exclude the default branch from searches. To list branches merged into the "main" branch, excluding the "main" branch itself: `git branch --format='%(if:notequals=main)%(refname:short)%(then)%(refname:short)%(end)' --merged=main`. For the "master" branch: `git branch --format='%(if:notequals=master)%(refname:short)%(then)%(refname:short)%(end)' --merged=master`

We can also combine the two, printing the branch name only if it matches neither "main" nor "master": `git branch --format='%(if:notequals=main)%(refname:short)%(then)%(if:notequals=master)%(refname:short)%(then)%(refname:short)%(end)%(end)' --merged`

The last one comes with a small caveat: you should check out the default branch (either "main" or "master", in this case) first, because `--merged` without a value means "merged into HEAD", which could be pointing to one of the branches you want to delete. But trying to delete the current local branch won't work anyway, so this is not a risk if that's what you're doing.

Another advantage of this approach is that there's no extra leading spaces or asterisk to filter out.

These commands *will* print an empty line rather than nothing for the excluded branch, but `xargs` takes care of that. If you want to process the lines using something other than `xargs` you might need special handling for the empty lines (like passing through `sed '/^$/d'`)

See `git help for-each-ref` for more info about `--format`.

Answer (score 0):

Windoze-friendly Python script (because `git-sweep` choked on Wesnoth repository):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Remove merged git branches. Cross-platform way to execute:
#
#   git branch --merged | grep -v master | xargs git branch -d
#
# Requires gitapi - https://bitbucket.org/haard/gitapi
# License: Public Domain

import gitapi

repo = gitapi.Repo('.')
output = repo.git_command('branch', '--merged').strip()
for branch in output.split('\n'):
  branch = branch.strip()
  if branch.strip(' *') != 'master':
    print(repo.git_command('branch', '-d', branch).strip())
```

https://gist.github.com/techtonik/b3f0d4b9a56dbacb3afc

Answer (score 0):

If you are using branching model like HubFlow or GitFlow you can use this command to remove the merged feature branches:

```sh
git branch --merged | grep feature.* | grep -v "\*" | xargs -n 1 git branch -d
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to delete local branches that have been merged as well as delete their remotes here's the one-liner I prefer:

```bash
git branch --merged | xargs -I_br -- sh -c 'git branch -d _br; git push origin --delete _br'
```

Answer (score 0):

[My Bash script contribution](https://gist.github.com/rocketraman/edb0a2aac74004d8d6b482690d7c62e3) is based loosely on [mmrobin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12631656/430128).

It takes some useful parameters specifying includes and excludes, or to examine/remove only local or remote branches instead of both.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# exclude branches regex, configure as "(remote|branch1|branch2|etc)$"
excludes_default="(upstream|master|main|next|maint.*|proposed.*)$"
excludes=
includes=
base=master
merged="--merged"
local=1
remote=1

while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
  case "$1" in
  -i) shift; includes="$includes $1" ;;
  -e) shift; excludes="$excludes $1" ;;
  -b) shift; base="$1" ;;
  --no-local) local=0 ;;
  --no-remote) remote=0 ;;
  --all) merged= ;;
  *) echo "Unknown argument $1"; exit 1 ;;
  esac
  shift   # next option
done

if [ "$excludes" == "" ]; then
  excludes="__NOTHING__"
else
  excludes="($(echo $excludes | sed -e 's/ /|/g'))"
fi

if [ "$includes" == "" ]; then
  includes=".*"
else
  includes="($(echo $includes | sed -e 's/ /|/g'))"
fi

current_branch=$(git branch --no-color 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/\1/')
if [ "$current_branch" != "$base" ]; then
  echo "ERROR: You are on branch $current_branch, NOT $base. Change branch or specify base with -b."
  exit 1
fi
echo -e "NOTE: no fetch performed, do it manually...\n"

remotes=$(git remote)
remote_branches=$(git branch --no-color --format="%(refname)" -r $merged \
  | grep -v HEAD | grep -v "/$current_branch$" | grep -v -E "$excludes" | grep -v -E "$excludes_default" | grep -E "$includes" \
  | sed -e 's|refs/remotes/||g' -e 's|refs/heads/||g')
local_branches=$(git branch --no-color --format="%(refname)" $merged \
  | grep -v HEAD | grep -v "$current_branch$" | grep -v -E "$excludes" | grep -v -E "$excludes_default" | grep -E "$includes" \
  | sed -e 's|refs/remotes/||g' -e 's|refs/heads/||g')

if [ -z "$remote_branches" ] && [ -z "$local_branches" ]; then
  echo "No existing branches have been merged into $current_branch."
else
  echo "This will remove the following branches:"
  if [ "$remote" == 1 -a -n "$remote_branches" ]; then
    echo "$remote_branches"
  fi
  if [ "$local" == 1 -a -n "$local_branches" ]; then
    echo "$local_branches"
  fi
  read -p "Continue? (y/n): " -n 1 choice
  echo
  if [ "$choice" == "y" ] || [ "$choice" == "Y" ]; then
    if [ "$remote" == 1 ]; then
      # Remove remote branches
      if [ -z "$remotes" ]; then
        echo "No remote branches removed."
      fi
      for remote in $remotes
      do
        branches=$(echo -n "$remote_branches" | grep "$remote/" | sed "s/$remote\/?\(.*\)/:\1 /g" | tr '\n' ' ')
        git push $remote $branches 
      done
    fi

    if [ "$local" == 1 ]; then
      # Remove local branches
      locals=$(echo -n "$local_branches" | tr '\n' ' ')
      if [ -z "$locals" ]; then
        echo "No local branches removed."
      else
        git branch -d "$locals"
      fi
    fi
  fi
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

`git-delete-merged-branches` from `git-extras` repo.

https://github.com/tj/git-extras/blob/master/Commands.md#git-delete-merged-branches

Answer (score 0):

Given you want to delete the merged branches, you need to delete the remote-tracking branches only, unless you state otherwise.

So to delete those branches you can do it by

`git branch --remote --merged origin/master | egrep -v "(^\*|master|development)" | cut -b 10- | xargs git push --delete origin`

This will delete all merged branches (merged to master) except `master` and `development`.

Answer (score 0):

I use a Python script which automates the steps from the most [popular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6127884/434243) and also checks remaining branches to see if they would produce any changes if merged and interactively prompts to delete them if not: https://github.com/robertknight/prune-merged-branches.

Answer (score 0):

Same @Adam Dymitruk 's answer, but with some improvements/fixes...

## How do I delete all Git branches which have been merged?

First, list locally/remotely tracking branches that were merged in remote...

**NOTE:** You might see few branches that you don't want to remove. We can add few arguments ("grep") to skip important branches that you don't want to delete like "master" or a "hom"...

**FOR LOCALLY-TRACKING BRANCHES**

```
git branch --merged | grep -vE '(master|hom)$'
```

**FOR REMOTE-TRACKING BRANCHES**

```
git branch --remotes --merged | grep -vE 'origin/(master|hom)$'
```

To delete all locally/remotely tracking branches that are already merged into the CURRENTLY CHECKED OUT BRANCH (normally "main" or "master")...

**FOR LOCALLY-TRACKING BRANCHES**

```
git branch --merged | grep -vE '(master|hom)$' | xargs git branch --delete
```

**FOR REMOTE-TRACKING BRANCHES**

```
git branch --remotes --merged | grep -vE 'origin/(master|hom)$' | sed 's/ origin\///' | xargs git push --delete origin
```

**TIP:** To use multiple resulting commands use "xargs -n 1".

**NOTE:** If it's not merged (WARNING! ⚠️), use `git branch --delete --force`.

---

### Improvements

- The "grep" commands are safer because they match the names "by the whole" and by the end of the string. In other words, less risk of matching the part of the branch name.
- The command...

```
git branch --remotes --merged | grep -vE 'origin/(master|hom)$' | sed 's/ origin\///' | xargs git push --delete origin
```

...effectively deletes branches remotely.

- More organized and succinct procedure.

Comment: Then you might want to explicitly highlight what are the differences and how your answer improves on the linked answer.

Comment: @mozway Done! =D

Answer (score -1):

The following creates an alias `git cleanup` with one optional parameter branch. By default it uses the default branch of remote origin. Every branch that has been merged into this will be deleted. There also is a `-d` /`--dryrun` option to show what would be deleted.

#### Setup

```
git config --global alias.cleanup '!COMMAND="git branch -D"; while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do case "$1" in -d|--dryrun) COMMAND="echo"; shift; ;; *) MAIN_BRANCH="$1"; shift;; esac; done; MAIN_BRANCH="${MAIN_BRANCH:-$(git symbolic-ref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD)}"; git for-each-ref --merged="$MAIN_BRANCH" --no-contains="$MAIN_BRANCH" --format="%(refname:short)" refs/heads/ | xargs -n1 -r $COMMAND;#'
```

#### Usage:

```
git cleanup             # delete all branches that have been merged into origin/HEAD
git cleanup master2     # delete all branches that have been merged into master2
git cleanup master2 -d  # do a dryrun (show names of branches that would be delted)
```

#### Readable code

Who can read that "oneliner"? Well here you go

```
COMMAND="git branch -D";
while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
  case "$1" in
    -d|--dryrun)
      COMMAND="echo"; 
      shift; 
      ;; 
    *)
      MAIN_BRANCH="$1";
      shift
    ;;
  esac;
done;
MAIN_BRANCH="${MAIN_BRANCH:-$(git symbolic-ref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD)}"; 
git for-each-ref --merged="$MAIN_BRANCH" --no-contains="$MAIN_BRANCH" --format="%(refname:short)" refs/heads/ | xargs -n1 -r $COMMAND;
#
```

#### What is different to the other answers?

- uses `--no-contains` option to filter out the identity branch (branch into which all other branches that are deleted have been merged) instead of `grep -v` (this works better if you are specific about your branch and specify refs/heads/master for example)
- uses the remote HEAD to check for the default branch name
- has a parameter to specify which branch to use as merge master
- has a dryrun option

Comment: This removes the master branch