# How can I clean up old git branches?

Tags: git

First, I've found other questions on cleaning up old branches on remotes.

What I'd really like is a command that looks for all branches that are merged and older than some threshold (say 2 weeks). Then deletes that local and remote branch.

Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I delete all Git branches which have been merged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127328/how-can-i-delete-all-git-branches-which-have-been-merged)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Be interesting to see what other say - since I am not a git expert - but you do have these options.

First find a commit which is two weeks old

```
git log -n 1 --format="%h %aD" --until="@{2 weeks ago}"
b4f2ff3 Fri, 28 Oct 2011 08:36:56 -0600
```

Show unmerged branches since that commit

```
git branch --no-merged b4f2ff3
  foo
* master
  views_to_tables
```

Show merged branches since that commit

```
git branch --merged b4f2ff3
  Hday.mt
  commod_stat
  commodity_stat_SP
  merged
  printscheman
  program_options
  release
  test
```

Delete local branch

```
git branch -d <branchname>
```

Delete remote branch

```
git push origin :<branchname>
```