# How to remove all local git branches but keep master with one command line?

Tags: git

I have created many branches in local and remote. I want delete all the branch from local as well as remote.

Note:I don't want delete each and every branches one by one.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete all local git branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610327/delete-all-local-git-branches)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should make a copy of the repo, before doing this. So, that in case of any unwanted changes, you can recover easily.

You can run the following command from your repo root.

```
git branch --merged master | grep -v master | xargs git branch -d
```