# Batch file that will delete all local branches (git) in each subfolder of a directory

Tags: git, batch-file

Here is my requirement:

1. Iterate through all the subfolders of the given directory.
2. In each subfolder, delete all local branches except master branch.

For item#2, the following statement works when manually executed in a subfolder.

```
git branch | grep -v " master" | xargs git branch -D
```

I want to create a batch file that will execute the above statement in each subfolder.

I tried the following but could not make it work. Please help me identify what's wrong with the statement.

```
FOR /D %%G in ("C:\parent\*") Do (echo Updating %%G ...) && (cd %%G) && git branch | grep -v " master" | xargs git branch -D
```

Comment: Remove the parantheses after `do`. Correct syntax is `for %%G in (path) do (command&&command)`. I also suggest using `&` (or better yet, new lines), as `&&` means "do upon success".

Comment: @Regejok - Wouldn't it make sense to _not_ run the `git` command if the `cd` failed?

Comment: @SomethingDark I guess it's the same thing either way, because it's only going to fail if the path contains spaces (in which case you'd need `cd "%%G"`). It would just attempt to delete the branch a second time.

Answer (score 0):

> In each subfolder, delete all local branches except master branch.

That is not how Git works. That might make sense with Subversion, not Git.
Once you have deleted a branch, that branch is gone for the *all* repo, not for a subfolder.

The only case where you could delete a branch in a Git repo subfolder is if that subfolder is the root folder is a **[submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)**.

Plus, you might consider using `-d` instead of `-D`, to avoid deleting branches not fully merged. See "[Can I delete all the local branches except the current one?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28572427/6309)".

Answer (score 0):

thank you for all the help.

It turns out that I am encountering the following error:

```
'grep' is not recognized as an internal or extenal command.
```

I did not see it because I execute the batch file by double clicking it, then command prompt will display and immediately close so I missed the error message.

Anyway, the batch file with the contents above worked as expected when I execute it using Git bash.

Note that this is only for maintenance purposes, assuming that I only need the master branch and all local branches are merged.