# Running git.exe commands with vertical bar from batch (.bat) file

Tags: git, batch-file

I want to delete all git local branches (except master) from *.bat file using command:

```
git.exe branch | grep -v "master" | xargs git branch -D
```

But this string includes "|" and the command fails.

Also doesn't work:

```
git.exe "branch | grep -v "master" | xargs git branch -D"
```

and

```
git.exe branch ^| grep -v "master" ^| xargs git branch -D
```

Comment: How does the command fail? What error message do you see?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem with using git alias.

```
[alias]
    dellocbr = !sh -c \"git branch | grep -v \"master\" | xargs git branch -D\" -
```

Run into batch:

```
git dellocbr
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50760584/7110564), you can do a batch script like this :

```
@echo off
REM -- Variable declerations
set "textFile=tempBranchInfo.txt"
set "branchToKeep=master"
set "branchToReplaceWith="
git checkout master
git branch > %textFile%

REM -- remove "master" from list to keep the branch
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%textFile%" ^& break ^> "%textFile%" ') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    >>"%textFile%" echo(!line:%branchToKeep%=%branchToReplaceWith%!
    endlocal
)

REM -- execute branch delete commands
for /f "delims=" %%a in (%textFile%) do (
    git branch -D %%a
)

REM -- remove temp-file with branch information inside
DEL %textFile%

REM -- show local branches after the cleaning
echo Local branches:
git branch

pause 
exit
```

It gonna use a temporary file to store the name of the branches to delete.