# How to delete all Git remote branches except master?

Tags: github, git

Looking for a command to delete all branches on Git repository except for master and push them to remote.

This is to clean up Git repository before making a release as the previous history branches everything else are totally dev changes and doesn't matter.

Comment: This sounds kind of dangerous especially if the team is working on new features for a future release. You may take a look at a branching strategy named Git Flow. This strategy makes it such that as soon as you are done with a branch and have merged it up, that it should then be deleted. https://leanpub.com/git-flow/read

Comment: **See Also**: [Delete all local git branches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10610327/1366033)

Answer (score 78):

This will remove all branches (except for `master`), even if the branch has a slash '/' in it:

```
git branch -r | grep 'origin' | grep -v 'master$' | grep -v HEAD | cut -d/ -f2- | while read line; do git push origin :heads/$line; done;
```

This will do the same, leaving both `develop` and `master` branches alone:

```
git branch -r | grep 'origin' | grep -v 'master$' | grep -v 'develop$' | grep -v HEAD | cut -d/ -f2- | while read line; do git push origin :heads/$line; done;
```

This is the script for fish shell:

```
git branch -r | grep 'origin' | grep -v 'master$' | grep -v 'develop$' | grep -v HEAD | cut -d/ -f2- | while read line; git push origin :heads/$line; end;
```

Comment: this ask passphrase for each branch

Comment: This solution will run multiple `git push origin ...` commands, one for each branch to be removed. If your git configuration requires authentication for each `git push` and this is not as intended, you may consider using SSH auth or looking into your git configuration. I `git push` without interactive auth, so the command above executes without any intervention or additional steps.  As they say, YMMV.

Comment: Brilliant my friend.

Comment: Best answer out there

Comment: ```git branch -r | grep 'origin' | grep -v 'main$' | grep -v HEAD | cut -d/ -f2- | while read line; do git push origin :heads/$line; done; ```

Comment: As some of the branches in my repo contained the word _master_ (e.g. _feature/my-integration-master_) I had to adjust the syntax slightly: `git branch -r | grep 'origin' | grep -v 'origin/master$' | grep -v HEAD | cut -d/ -f2- | while read line; do git push origin :heads/$line; done;`

Answer (score 2):

Finally below command just worked like charm for me, you can tweak it for further requirements.

```
git branch -r | grep origin/ | grep -v 'master$' | grep -v HEAD| cut -d/ -f2 | while read line; do git push origin :$line; done;
```

Comment: why don't you just approve @staxim answer your's is the same, just write a comment below his that is `origin/` instead of `'origin'`

Comment: this is a copy of the previous answer. Please just upvote that rather than repeat it.

Comment: @RichieHH I may be missing something, but it looks like willsteel's answer was posted on the day he asked his question while staxim's answer was posted a few months later. It would seem better if staxim had edited willsteel's answer instead of posting his own

Comment: I use this all the time, lol.

Answer (score 0):

Bash oneliner, without for-loop etc, but yes, need to parse some things:

```bash
git branch -r  | grep -v master | cut -d "/" -f2 | xargs git push --delete origin
```

PoW:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To delete all branches in a Git repository except for the master branch and push the changes to the remote repository, you can use the following commands:

```
# Delete all branches except master locally
git branch | grep -v 'master' | xargs git branch -D

# Delete all branches except master remotely
git push origin --delete $(git branch -r | grep -v 'origin/master' | sed 's/origin\///')

# Push changes to remote repository
git push origin --prune
```

Answer (score -3):

Can use below command, it will remove all branches except master and the current one

`git branch | grep -v "master\|$(git branch --show-current)" | xargs git branch -D`

Comment: This will remove local branches, and the author asks about remote branches

Comment: Better to read the question rather than give a potentially dangerous answer. This removes LOCAL branches potentially destroying weeks of work.

Comment: This is actually what I was looking for even though it didn't answer the question lol