# Delete all commits not on master

Tags: git

I have a local git repository with a couple of branches. I want to locally delete all non-master branches, as well as the commits that are not on the master branch. How do I delete all commits that are not on the master branch?

I am later doing a cherry-pick that fails because it reaches a commit that was a merge, so it has two parents. What do I need to do so that it only has one parent (from the master branch)?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10610327/6327676

Answer (score 4):

```
git branch | grep -v "master$" | xargs git branch -D
```

The above will get all branches, filter out those that include "master", and then delete them.

When Git next does garbage collection, the now-orphaned commits will be deleted.  If you want to force that to happen now, you can run:

```
git gc --prune=now --aggressive
```

Comment: I am later doing a cherry-pick that fails because it reaches a commit that was a merge, so it has two parents. What do I need to do so that it only has one parent (from the master branch)?

Comment: 'git branch' is porcelain its output shouldn't be relied upon. It is better to use a low level command such as 'for-each-ref'

```git for-each-ref --format='delete %(refname)' refs/heads | grep -v 'refs/heads/master' | git update-ref --stdin```

Comment: Can you explain this long command? Will it delete all the diffs not on the master branch?

Answer (score 1):

The part of your question about deleting all non-master branches is already answered.  However:

> I am later doing a cherry-pick that fails because it reaches a commit that was a merge, so it has two parents. What do I need to do so that it only has one parent (from the master branch)?

You can't do anything about this.  No *existing* commit can ever be changed: not by you, nor by Git.  If you're deleting branch names with the idea that this might also change existing commits, it won't: all it will do is make it impossible to *find* some existing commits.

Once a commit is un-find-able (*unreachable*, in technical terms), `git gc` will (eventually) delete it entirely.  But a *merge commit*, with its two parents, makes both parents find-able: finding the merge—by starting at some branch name and working backwards through history—inherently finds *both* parents, and then the parents' parents, and so on.

For (much) more about this, see [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).

What you *probably* want to do, rather than trying to modify this existing commit, is one of these two things:

- Don't cherry-pick the merge at all.  Cherry-pick, instead, all of the commits *behind* the merge (on both legs / sides of the merge).
- Or, do cherry-pick the merge, but use `git cherry-pick -m number` to specify *which parent* will produce the diffs for the cherry-pick.

You can think of `git cherry-pick` as meaning: *Take the snapshot (commit) I name, and turn it into changes (diffs against its parent), then apply those same diffs to my current commit.*  That's just an approximation though.

You might have a series of commits that can be drawn like this:

```
          o--o--A--B--o--...--o   <-- branch1
         /
...--o--*
         \
          o--o--o--C   <-- branch2 (HEAD)
```

Here, your current commit is commit `C` (C stands in for its actual hash) and you're on branch `branch1`.  If you `git cherry-pick B`, Git compares `A` vs `B` and merges whatever happened there with the difference between `A` and `C`.  Cherry-pick is therefore actually a *merge*, not a diff-and-apply; this is what leads to weird merge conflicts sometimes.

In any case, this obviously only works for non-merge commits, because a merge has two parents:

```
       o--...--A
      /         \
...--*           M--...
      \         /
       o--...--B
```

If you ask to cherry-pick `M`, should Git compare `M` to `A`, or to `B`?  Which of `A` and `B` gets compared to your current commit?

The cherry-pick command's `-m` switch allows you to *choose*.  If you choose `A`, Git will merge the `A`-to-`M` changes with the `A`-to-`HEAD` changes.  The effect is to take all the changes that the merge introduced because of commit `B`!  So this means you no longer need to cherry-pick some commits *behind* `B`.  You got *all* of "their" (B's) changes relative to the merge base commit `*`—or rather, all that whoever did the merge into `A` thought were appropriate to keep.

Note that you still might want commits behind `A`, including commit `*` itself and things earlier.  Or you may not, depending on what, exactly, you're doing.  Git mostly provides *tools* rather than solutions; it's up to you to make use of these tools, however you like.