# Git cherry-pick delete non-master branches and diffs

Tags: git

I am doing a git cherry-pick and getting the following error:

error: commit b9697dde3318c2a195671015be2b991321207659 is a merge but no -m option was given.
fatal: cherry-pick failed

I'd like to fix this by deleting all the non-master branches and diffs, so that the commit above only has one parent commit (the one that's on the master branch). How do I do this?

Comment: See my answer to your earlier question https://stackoverflow.com/q/57362621/1256452