# What does git rev-parse do?

Tags: git, git-rev-parse

What does `git rev-parse` do?

I have read the man page but it raised more questions than answers. Things like:

> Pick out and **massage** parameters

*Massage*? What does that mean?

I'm using as a resolver (to SHA1) of revision specifiers, like

```
git rev-parse HEAD^
```

or

```
git rev-parse origin/master
```

Is this the command’s purpose? If not, is even correct to use it to achieve this?

Comment: As far as I can see in the man page, it's a mostly internal utility to parse revision/object names for other commands. What you're doing is pretty much the purpose of the `rev-parse` command. You can also use it to normalize a command line, so that the actual program doesn't have to understand the complicated object name syntax of Git (you'd use `git rev-parse` to change, or "massage", certain parameters in the command line before the actual program is called).

Comment: See also https://github.com/git/git/commit/b2a2c4d8099c69ec997e51cac489c0947ad17956

Comment: The man page for `git rev-parse` is laughably incomprehensible. I'm surprised nobody has bothered to rewrite that jargon into something human readable, even after 5 years.

Comment: @not2qubit Me: 'Thank you for clarifying, I was feeling inferior.' 
Linus Torvalds: 'I re-read it, exactly what part did you not comprehend?'

Comment: Nobody can rewrite it if nobody can understand it

Answer (score 380, accepted):

[`git rev-parse`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse) is an ancillary `plumbing` command primarily used for manipulation.

One common usage of `git rev-parse` is to print the SHA1 hashes given a revision specifier. In addition, it has various options to format this output such as `--short` for printing a shorter unique SHA1.

There are other use cases as well (in scripts and other tools built on top of git) that I've used for:

- `--verify` to verify that the specified object is a valid git object.
- `--git-dir` for displaying the abs/relative path of the `.git` directory.
- Checking if you're currently within a repository using `--is-inside-git-dir` or within a work-tree using `--is-inside-work-tree`
- Checking if the repo is a bare using `--is-bare-repository`
- Printing SHA1 hashes of branches (`--branches`), tags (`--tags`) and the refs can also be filtered based on the remote (using `--remote`)
- `--parse-opt` to normalize arguments in a script (kind of similar to `getopt`) and print an output string that can be used with `eval`

`Massage` just implies that it is possible to convert the info from one form into another i.e. a transformation command. These are some quick examples I can think of:

- a branch or tag name into the commit's SHA1 it is pointing to so that it can be passed to a plumbing command which only accepts SHA1 values for the commit.
- a revision range `A..B` for `git log` or `git diff` into the equivalent arguments for the underlying plumbing command as `B ^A`

Answer (score 188):

Just to elaborate on the etymology of the command name `rev-parse`, Git consistently uses the term `rev` in plumbing commands as short for "revision" and generally meaning the 40-character SHA1 hash for a commit. The command `rev-list` for example prints a list of 40-char commit hashes for a branch or whatever.

In this case the name might be expanded to `parse-a-commitish-to-a-full-SHA1-hash`. While the command has the several ancillary functions mentioned in Tuxdude's answer, its namesake appears to be the use case of transforming a user-friendly reference like a branch name or abbreviated hash into the unambiguous 40-character SHA1 hash most useful for many programming/plumbing purposes.

I know I was thinking it was "reverse-parse" something for quite a while before I figured it out and had the same trouble making sense of the terms "massaging" and "manipulation" :)

Anyway, I find this "parse-to-a-revision" notion a satisfying way to think of it, and a reliable concept for bringing this command to mind when I need that sort of thing. Frequently in scripting Git you take a user-friendly commit reference as user input and generally want to get it resolved to a validated and unambiguous working reference as soon after receiving it as possible. Otherwise input translation and validation tends to proliferate through the script.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I didn't understand the git-docs one bit: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse

Comment: can you give us  an example of `messaging` and `manipulation` as you allude to before?

Comment: In other words, `git rev-parse` is short for `git revision-parse`. It takes the given input and returns the corresponding 40-character revision ID.

Comment: git doc itself is like plumbing, and this answer is the porcelain.

Comment: Wow, it turns out that `git rev-parse` is actually extremely simple to understand. Why is the manual page written in such hieroglyphics?

Answer (score 63):

`git rev-parse` Also works for getting the current branch name using the [--abbrev-ref](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt---abbrev-refstrictloose) flag like:

```
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
```

Comment: Is it popssible to get a commit message in this way?

Comment: @LeoDroidcoder try `git log --format=%B -n 1 <revision>`

Comment: Any way to ensure this is actually a branch?

Answer (score 27):

**TLDR:**

It helps you to find out the commit ID of the current HEAD (i.e. the current commit you are viewing)

```
git rev-parse HEAD
```

OR if you want the shorter commit

```
git rev-parse --short HEAD
```

If you want to find the latest commit in another branch, you can do

```
git rev-parse <local-branch-name>
git rev-parse origin/<remote-branch-name>
```