# git rev-parse --short HEAD

Tags: git

What does the following command do?:

```
git rev-parse --short HEAD
```

The answer should include:

1. A short and to the point answer that explains what this command does as a whole
2. Explanation of rev-parse
3. Explanation of --short
4. Explanation of HEAD

Comment: Shouldn't you do your own homework? (If it's not a homework question, it really needs a lot of rephrasing...)

Comment: @torek I'm not asking for myself. I already know the answer. I've just seen that there is no question on SO regarding this specific command, and it could help programmers if such a question existed.

Comment: If you know the answer, you should also post it...

Comment: I doubt there is a point in copy-pasting the documentation for every git command or whatnot onto Stack Overflow camoflaged as a question. They had a documentation part of the site previously, but it was decomissioned.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does git rev-parse do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798862/what-does-git-rev-parse-do)

Comment: Also, what is HEAD is a separate question from what git rev-parse does, please don't post more than one question at a time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`git rev-parse --short`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt---shortlength) is both a way to:

- [verify that it can be turned into a raw 20-byte SHA-1 that can be used to access the object database](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt---verify)
- get an abbreviated SHA (SHA1 for now, [SHA2 later on](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47838703/6309)), respecting core.abbrev setting (as [I mention here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21015031/6309)), 7 characters by default.
  But if 7 characters is not enough to produce a unique SHA, git rev-parse will generate the right length.

Applied to HEAD, it gets back a short version of the SHA1 of the currently checked out commit (which is not necessarily a branch, [when the HEAd is detached](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309))

You can see it used for the first time in the git/git code base itself in [commit e3ae4a8613151c93ffce78c674ac91c1ee34eef6, Aug. 2009, Git v1.6.5-rc0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e3ae4a8613151c93ffce78c674ac91c1ee34eef6).

> The substring expansion notation is a bashism that we have not so far
> adopted.
> Use 'git rev-parse --short' instead, as this also handles the case where the unique abbreviation is longer than 7 characters.

So instead of:

```
${sub1sha1:0:7}
```

Use:

```
sub1sha1_short=$(cd clone3/sub1 && git rev-parse --short HEAD)
$sub1sha1_short
```

You find it used then in [commit e8f21ca, June 2013, Git v1.8.4-rc0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e8f21caf94287d838cfffe8301b28fdc45480ac8), for the bash prompt:

> ### bash prompt: print unique detached HEAD abbreviated object name

> When describing a detached HEAD according to the `$GIT_PS1_DESCRIBE` environment variable fails, `__git_ps1()` runs '`cut -c1-7 .git/HEAD`' to show the 7 hexdigits abbreviated commit object name in the prompt.
> Obviously, this neither respects `core.abbrev` nor produces a unique object name.

> Fix this by using '`git rev-parse --short HEAD`' instead and adjust the corresponding test to use non-standard number of hexdigits.

Because `--short` will compute the minimum lenght for a SHA to be non-ambiguous, it should be the last option used by git rev-parse.

See [commit e3e0b93, also June 2013, Git v1.8.4-rc0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e3e0b9378b6e51ea50c023d92d4d2a1f4d4cc676)

> ### bash prompt: combine 'git rev-parse' for detached head

> When describing a detached HEAD according to the `$GIT_PS1_DESCRIBE` environment variable fails, `__git_ps1()` now runs the '`$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)`' command substitution to get the abbreviated detached HEAD commit object name.
> This imposes the overhead of fork()ing a subshell and fork()+exec()ing a `git` process.
>
> Avoid this overhead by combining this command substitution with the
> "main" '`git rev-parse`' execution for getting the path to the `.git` directory & co.
> This means that we'll look for the abbreviated commit object name even when it's not necessary, because we're on a branch or the detached HEAD can be described.
> It doesn't matter, however, because once '`git rev-parse`' is up and running to fulfill all those other queries, the additional overhead of looking for the abbreviated commit object name is not measurable because it's lost in the noise.
>
> There is a caveat, however, when we are on an unborn branch, because in that case HEAD doesn't point to a valid commit, hence the query for the abbreviated commit object name fails.
> Therefore, '`--short HEAD`' must be the last options to '`git rev-parse`' in order to get all the other necessary information for the prompt even on an unborn branch.
> Furthermore, in that case, and in that case only, '`git rev-parse`' doesn't output the last line containing the abbreviated commit object name, obviously, so we have to take care to only parse it if '`git rev-parse`' exited without any error.