# fatal: bad config file line in .gitconfig file when making an alias for deleting merged branches

Tags: git

Can anyone help me figure out what is wrong with this line in the .gitconfig file?

```
[alias]
db = !git branch --merged | grep -v "\*" | xargs -n 1 git branch -d
```

The command by itself works, I was following along this post ([How can I delete all git branches which have been merged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127328/how-can-i-delete-all-git-branches-which-have-been-merged))

But when I run the alias 'git db' it will fail with 'fatal: bad config file line 22' which points to that line in my .gitconfig file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To expand on the comment by MrTux: quotes (`""`) have special meaning in a Git config file. If you want to use them in a config value, you have to escape them and then quote the entire value, like this:

```
db = "!git branch --merged | grep -v \"*\" | xargs -n 1 git branch -d"
```

Comment: And so do backslashes, e.g.: `foobar '!@#$\"'\'` would become `"foobar '!@#$\\\"'\\'"`