# What happens to a branch once I merge it?

Tags: git, version-control, merge, branch

I create the master and then a branch (named `the_branch`)  out of it.  I modified the the_branch and then

```
git checkout master  
git merge the_branch  
git commit -m "..."  
git push
```

Seems like code was merge and all seems right. **My question**, if I want `the_branch` to "die" once I merge it, do I have to **explicitly delete it**, or there is a way that once I merge a branch into another it dies by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### local branch

git does not delete the branch unless you tell it to with

```
git branch -d the_branch
```

### remote branch

as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127328/how-can-i-delete-all-git-branches-which-have-been-merged):

> To delete it from the remote in old versions of Git use:
>
> ```
> git push origin :branchname
> ```
>
> In more recent versions of Git use:
>
> ```
> git push --delete origin branchname
> ```

Comment: correct, I expanded the answer to include the remote branch answer as well