# How to alias in git delete merged branches

Tags: windows, git, bash, github

I'm trying to alias the command:

```
git branch --merged | grep -v "\*" | grep -v master | xargs -n 1 git branch -d
```

[Taken from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6127884/601179)

This is my `.gitconfig` file:

```
[credential]
    helper = wincred
[user]
    name = Doron Grinzaig
    email = doron@doNotSpamMe.Suckers
[push]
    default = simple
[alias]
    db = git branch --merged | grep -v "\*" | grep -v master | grep -v dev | xargs -n 1 git branch -d
    unstage = reset HEAD --
```

But now when I try to edit the .gitconfig file I get the error:

```
$ git config --global --edit
fatal: bad config file line 9 in C:\Users\Doron Grinzaig/.gitconfig
```

I was told I need to use `!` for running bash scripts as git alias, but the following returned the same error:

```
[alias]
    db = !git branch --merged | grep -v "\*" | grep -v master | grep -v dev | xargs -n 1 git branch -d
```

I'm using git bash for windows.

Comment: The "bad config file" error could be here for some other reason : bad EOL marker (`\r\n` instead of `\n`, or the reverse, I don't know what git expects on windows), maybe an unbreakable space somewhere ...  Try deleting and re-writing the whole [alias] section.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try escaping the quotes and backslash in the first grep command:

```
[alias]
    db = !git branch --merged | grep -v \"\\*\" | grep -v master | grep -v dev | xargs -n 1 git branch -d
```

Comment: Can be simplified a bit: `db = !"git branch --merged | grep -vE 'main|master|\\*' | xargs -n 1 git branch -D"`