# git alias to merge and delete branch

Tags: alias, git-merge

I'd like a git alias to merge then delete a *single* local branch. The question [How to alias in git delete merged branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35171513/how-to-alias-in-git-delete-merged-branches) addresses how to remove *all* merged branches; I'm essentially looking to keep my local repository clean as I go.

Answer (score 0):

```
mnd = "!f() { git merge --no-ff ${1} && git branch -d ${1}; }; f"
```