# Delete remote branches in origin that have already been merged

Tags: git, version-control, feature-branch

We are using a branch named 'integration' as our master branch (we still have a master, but we're not using it for now) and we have a bunch of branches that have been created off it then merged back in and need to be deleted. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127328/how-can-i-delete-all-git-branches-which-have-been-merged) about deleting local branches, but wasn't sure about applying the suggestions to my particular situation.

I *think* this will work, don't want to run this command and have it be wrong and screw up the repo.

> $ git checkout integration
>
> $ git branch -r --merged | grep -v integration| sed 's/origin//:/' | xargs -n 1 git push origin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape that `/`, make it `...sed 's/origin\//:/'...` but otherwise, sure, that would work.

To test stuff like this, just leave the `xargs` part off so you see what will happen.

Comment: That did it, thanks! Also, I was hoping for a way to 'test' the command before running it, so double kudos for adding the xargs part.