# Why is this a bad config line for my .gitconfig?

Tags: git, bash

```
bd = "!f() { git branch --merged | egrep -v '(^\*|master|dev)' | xargs git branch -d }; f"
```

I'm trying to alias a git command to remove all of my local merged branches.
 When I put the bash command into my gitconfig as above, git complains about a bad config line:
`fatal: bad config line 26 in file /Users/johnsona/.gitconfig`

Comment: Do you have it in the `[alias]` section?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd recommend making this a bash script in your PATH instead, and then calling that script in your git alias instead (or if it's in your PATH anyway, just name the file `git-bd`).

For example, make the file `~/bin/git-bd`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
git branch --merged | egrep -v '(^\*|master|dev)' | xargs git branch -d
```

Make the file executable with the command:

```
chmod +x ~/bin/git-bd
```

And make sure your `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile` or `.bash_login` file has the line:

```
export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

And you can either just call `git-bd` directly, or add the alias in your `.gitconfig` like so:

```
bd = "!git-bd"
```

To add to this answer, the reason you are getting a bad config error may be due to the back-slashes. The git-config will read them as is, so you need to escape them again with a second backslash.

Comment: IMO you should put your last paragraph first because it would answer the question before making a recommendation.

Comment: If you think that's a good idea feel free to edit. That does make sense to me, but I'm now on my phone and unable to make the edit myself

Comment: Would it be possible to write the function inside of my `.bash_profile` and then have the gitconfig reference the command from there?

Comment: I'm not completely certain, but it's worth trying. My suspicion is that it won't work because git probably won't be aware of your bash functions

Comment: Ya it's complaining saying `git-db: command not found`. Gonna give your solution a go and then check it.

Comment: It is, in fact, the lone backslash that leads to `fatal: bad config line 2 in file ...`. In my test, doubling it changes the error to `Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "}")` (because the shell function needs a semicolon before the `}`).

Answer (score 3):

To make @torek's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40181171/why-is-this-a-bad-config-line-for-my-gitconfig#comment67632655_40181427) more visible and expand on it: there are a couple of issues with your command like this, when you want to put it in your gitconfig, and the result can be made a bit simpler.

Suppose you want to alias the [following command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6127884/4126843):

```
git branch --merged | egrep -v "(^\*|master|dev)" | xargs git branch -d
```

- It uses `|` so you have to prepend the command with `!` (you already did this)
- It uses `"` so you either have to escape those with `\"` or use single `'` (also already fixed)
- It uses `\` so you have to escape it with `\\`.

**Result**:

```
[alias]
    delete-merged-branches = ! git branch --merged | egrep -v '(^\\*|master)' | xargs git branch -d
```

You could also run in bash (not that git will escape `\` for you, but you have to wrap in `"` so you need to escape those)

```
git config --global alias.delete-merged-branches "! git branch --merged | egrep -v '(^\*|master|dev)' | xargs git branch -d"
```