# How to clean the branch list?

Tags: git, git-branch

After cloning a repo from the remote, I am on the `master` branch. When typing `git branch` to view the branch list, there's only `master` in the list.

Over time, checking out existing branches as well as creating new branches, eventually merging new work into `master` and pushing to `origin`. Now, typing `git branch` shows a long list with dozens of branches.

How can I reduce the list, removing specific branches from the list while retaining others on the list?

**Update 1**: To clarify, I am not interested in deleting any branch from the repo (and *definitely* not from the remote repo). Just making it easier to navigate between the subset of branches I regularly use at a given time.

**Update 2**: Consider -

```
$ git clone myrepo
$ git branch
        * master
$ git checkout mybranch
$ git branch
          master
        * mybranch
$ git checkout master
$ git branch
        * master
          mybranch
$ git "I'll not be dealing with mybranch for 91 days, do something to clean the list"
$ git branch
        * master

(playing DOOM for 91 days)

$ git checkout mybranch
$ git branch
          master
        * mybranch
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git branch` command lists branches using files from the location `.git/refs/heads`, here you can find files with branch names. Each file in this location corresponds to a branch, remove the files for which you don't want to see the branch in `git branch` command's output.

```
$ git branch
* branch-1
  master
  trunk
$ ls .git/refs/heads/
branch-1  master  trunk
$ rm .git/refs/heads/master
$ git branch
* branch-1
  trunk
$
```

Comment: Thanks. I had to re-clone my repo recently, so the problem went away for now - but this looks promising and I will check that when relevant. But isn't mangling with the `.git/` contents dangerous?

Comment: `.git/refs/heads/<branch name>` file has the latest commit-id of that branch.
Deleting this will not cause any issue, when we do `git checkout <branch name>` a new file is created and updated with the latest commit-id of that branch.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Once I can verify, I'll up-vote.

Comment: This is doing the trick. Hopefully it does not have any unseen side-effects.

Comment: This is weird. Coming back to this hack now that my branch list is again too long, and `ls`-ing the `heads` folder, some of the branch names I get in the `branch` command do not exist as files/subfolders. Any idea?

Comment: ... OTOH, I found the missing branches under the `logs` folder. But, strangely enough, there are many branches there that are not listed with the `branch` command.

Comment: I was so irritated with the long list of branches whenever I typed `git branch` . Thanks for solving my issue.

Answer (score 4):

> I don't want to delete the branches. I want them to still exist in the repo. I just want to clean the list

You would still need to delete those local branches. That won't delete them on the remote repo.

One good policy is to delete [any branch merged to `master`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41198505/6309).

```
git branch -d $(git branch --merged | grep -vw $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD))
```

Don't forget you can [restore any deleted branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3640806/6309) (if done within the past 90 days) through [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog).

Comment: Thanks. "You would still need to delete those local branches." - if this is the only way to achieve what I want, then I guess I'll just forget about this...

Comment: @ysap I don't get exactly what you mean by "clean the list". For me, cleaning the list means deleting local branches. But the git branch -a would still list those same branches as remote

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. Probably "clean" isn't the best term here. As I wrote in the question, every branch that I checkout gets added to the reported list, and it gets congested with time. Think about I just want to check what my colleague did in his branch so I check it out, and now it is "reported" forever. If I delete that branch (`-d`), then next time I check it out I get an error that the branch does not exist (obviously...). I want to remove it from the `git branch` list, but to be able to check it out easily anytime after that.

Comment: @ysap next time you want to checkout a branch deleted, a simple `git checkout -b abranch origin/abranch` is enough.

Comment: I see, but this relies on the assumption that the branch in origin is up to date, and that it even exists. Please see my 2nd update to the question.

Comment: @ysap yes, you need to push mybranch somewhere. Later, a simple `git fetch` will ensure that remote branch is back in your repo and up to date. The `checkout -b mybranch origin/mybranch` will then work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

At first, list all local branches:

```
$ git branch
```

We need to know what branches are already merged in “master” and can be easily removed:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git branch --merged
```

Now, remove all outdated branches with:

```
$ git branch -d old-merged-feature
```

Next, decide what to do with not merged branches:

```
$ git branch --no-merged
```

If some of them is just abandoned stuff that you don’t need anymore, remove it with “-D” option:

```
$ git branch -D old-abandoned-feature
```

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure it makes sense, but I don't want to *delete* the branches. I want them to still exist in the repo. I just want to clean the list. Apparently, of the 100's of branches in the repo, the list contains only those I actually checked out or created since cloning.

Comment: Look up git prune that might be more of what your after.