# How can I delete all Git remote branches which are older than a year?

Tags: git, github, version-control, branch, feature-branch

I have a LOT of GIT branches on my "remote" server.

1. How can I delete ALL branches (Not just merged) that are older than 1 year?
2. How can I also delete all merged branches (multiple origins "master/develop") older than 5 months?

This answer is quite nice, but it doesn't get me all the way there.
[How can I delete all Git branches which have been merged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127328/how-can-i-delete-all-git-branches-which-have-been-merged)

Can you please include master/develop branches from the merge?  How do I add a time interval on this?

```
git branch -r --merged | grep -v master | sed 's/origin\///' | xargs -n 1 git push --delete origin
```

Comment: I know this doesn't quite answer your question, but GitHub has a handy tool for this sort of work if the number of branches isn't too overwhelming. As far as I can tell, though, you have to enter the url manually: https://github.com/cyborgx37/sandbox/branches

Comment: Git doesn't store branch creation date as info. What you could look for is branches to which last commits were 1 year ago. For that you could try using git for-each-ref command: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref

Comment: I agree with @frennky. Additionally, what do you mean by "older than 1 year"? Most recent commit is older than 1 year old? First commit is older than 1 year old? (The concept of "first commit" is kind of fuzzy in git and may not be in any way obvious depending on what your history looks like.)

Answer (score 6):

You can use shell script to delete no merged branches which are older then one year, and delete the merged branches which are older than five months.

#### Delete no-merged branches which are older then one year

```sh
    #!/bin/bash
    
    tarBranch=$(git branch -r --no-merged | grep -v master | grep -v developer | sed 's/origin\///')
    for branch in $tarBranch
    do
     echo $branch
     lastDate=$(git show -s --format=%ci origin/$branch)
     convertDate=$(echo $lastDate | cut -d' ' -f 1)
     Todate=$(date -d "$convertDate" +'%s')
     current=$(date +'%s')
     day=$(( ( $current - $Todate )/60/60/24 ))
     echo "last commit on $branch branch was $day days ago"
     if [ "$day" -gt 365 ]; then
        git push origin :$branch
        echo "delete the old branch $branch"
     fi
    done
```

#### Delete the merged branches which are older than five months

```sh
    #!/bin/bash
    
    git checkout master
    #deleted merged branches on master branch
    tarBranch=$(git branch -r --merged | grep -v master | grep -v develop | sed 's/origin\///')
    for branch in $tarBranch
    do
     echo $branch
     lastDate=$(git show -s --format=%ci origin/$branch)
     convertDate=$(echo $lastDate | cut -d' ' -f 1)
     Todate=$(date -d "$convertDate" +'%s')
     current=$(date +'%s')
     day=$(( ( $current - $Todate )/60/60/24 ))
     echo "last commit on $branch branch was $day days ago"
     if [ "$day" -gt 150 ]; then
        git push origin :$branch
        echo "delete the old branch $branch"
     fi
    done

    git checkout develop
    #deleted merged branches on developer branch
    tarBranch=$(git branch -r --merged | grep -v master | grep -v develop | sed 's/origin\///')
    for branch in $tarBranch
    do
     echo $branch
     lastDate=$(git show -s --format=%ci origin/$branch)
     convertDate=$(echo $lastDate | cut -d' ' -f 1)
     Todate=$(date -d "$convertDate" +'%s')
     current=$(date +'%s')
     day=$(( ( $current - $Todate )/60/60/24 ))
     echo "last commit on $branch branch was $day days ago"
     if [ "$day" -gt 150 ]; then
        git push origin :$branch
        echo "delete the old branch $branch"
     fi
    done
```

Comment: can you write this in GIT Bash format?  Im having a tough time converting it properly.