# How do I clean both remote and local git branches on windows

Tags: windows, git

What is the best way to remove branch references that no longer exist and delete local branches already merged for git repos in **Windows** command prompt (i.e. not using bash)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I delete all Git branches which have been merged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127328/how-can-i-delete-all-git-branches-which-have-been-merged)

Answer (score 0):

This will first remove any remote tracking references that no longer exist and then proceed to enumerate and remove already merged local branches. The exception is that current, develop and master branches will be kept.

```
git fetch -p && for /f "tokens=1,2" %b in ('git branch --merged ^| findstr /v /c:"master" /c:"develop" /c:"*"') do (git branch -d %b)
```