# How to delete all remote branches merged into certain branches

Tags: git

if I have many remote branches merge into branch `DEV`, how do I list all remote branches merged into `DEV` and how to delete these remote branches.

```
git branch -r --merged <commit>
```

this command shows all remote branches are reachable from the specified commit.

but i don't know how to delete it. Please guide.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I delete all Git branches which have been merged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127328/how-can-i-delete-all-git-branches-which-have-been-merged)

Comment: @Cœur actually merged is right. thanks for your correction anyway :+1:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to delete all remote braches that merge is

```
git branch -r --merged | grep -v master | sed 's/origin\//:/' | xargs -n 1 git push origin
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `git branch -d branchname` if the branch is merged.

if the branch is not merged, you can use  `git branch -D branchname` to delete the specific branch.

Comment: is it deleting just local branches?

Comment: Yes ..do you want to delete remote as well ?