# Delete all branches that are no longer on Github

Tags: git, github

I have branches Branch-Master, Branch-A, Branch-B, Branch-C on GitHub. I usually merge into master and delete the merged branch.  This leaves a bunch of branches on my local machine, but not GitHub.

How do I automatically remove my local branches automatically? I want to create a git hook to do this.

When I try

```
git remote prune origin
```

and then run git branch, I still see all my branches, even the ones merged and deleted into master.

I know I can do

```
git branch -d {the_local_branch}
```

manually, but this does not help when doing a githook or I have multiple branches to remove systematically.

What I don't like about the answers given here:
[How can I delete all Git branches which have been merged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127328/how-can-i-delete-all-git-branches-which-have-been-merged)

Is that they are based off names, and inferring the deleted branch, rather than somehow explicitly passing a branch id, specific to that branch. What I understand in the link provided, is that if I create a branch name that is the same as the deleted branch, it will also be deleted, even though they are different branches.

[How do I delete a Git branch locally and remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-locally-and-remotely)

Does not address my inquiry, as it's solution is already stated above.

I would rather have some type of compare function using branch uid's if they exist.

Comment: Updated question, to show difference from both links

Comment: There is no way to do that automatically. There are no hooks for `git fetch/pull`. There is no such thing as *branch uid*: branch is a name and a pointer to a commit and nothing more.

Comment: The only way this can be done is with a script. Are you using Linux or Windows? I will hate to create the script for the wrong OS! :)

Answer (score 1):

As [phd noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56061869/delete-all-branches-that-are-no-longer-on-github?noredirect=1#comment98766341_56061869), there *is no underlying ID* for branches.  A branch name is simply a *local* name in *your* repository, created by you or at your request, that identifies one specific commit.  You can change this name any time, to any string you like as long as it meets [the requirements for a branch name](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ref-format).  Git won't remember that it used to have some other name.

Now, there are a few additional bits of information: your `.git/config` file can, and usually will, have in it, for each branch, some annotations such as:

```
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = master

[branch "develop"]
    remote = another-remote
    merge = develop
```

These settings define the *upstream setting* of the branch.  A branch can have no upstream at all—in which case the two settings are non-existent—or one upstream, in which case the two settings exist and describe the upstream, using the two parts from the old historical method of dealing with this before remote-tracking names were invented.

These configuration sections will automatically get renamed if you use standard Git commands to rename the branch.  For instance, after `git branch -m develop xyz`, you will have:

```
[branch "xyz"]
    remote = another-remote
    merge = develop
```

which means that the upstream of your local branch `xyz` is `another-remote/develop`.  (This assumes a standard `fetch =` setting for remote `another-remote`.)

It's possible, with some effort, to read through the upstream setting (if any) of each branch: use `git for-each-ref` to enumerate all branches, and then, for each branch, use `git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name <branch>@{upstream}` to see if it has an upstream, and if so, what the upstream name is.  Note that you must be a little bit careful here as the "remote" can be set to `.`, indicating that the upstream of some local branch is another local branch.

Combining this kind of programmatic test ("does branch X have an upstream, and if so, is it actually a remote-tracking name, and what remote-tracking name *is* it?") with a second test ("after using `git remote <remote> prune` or `git fetch <remote> --prune`, does the remote-tracking name exist?") may get you what you want.  You'll need to do some coding (bash scripting, for instance).  Making it optimal, or work from within a hook, is hard, but the overall task is pretty straightforward:

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads |
while read branch; do
    # make sure it has an upstream set -- if not, ignore
    upstream=$(git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name ${branch}@{upstream}) || continue
    # make sure the upstream is a remote-tracking name
    case $upstream in
    refs/remotes/*) ;;
    *) continue;;
    esac
    # get the name of the remote
    remote=${upstream#refs/remotes/}
    remote=${remote%%/*}
    # prune remote-tracking branches
    git remote $remote prune
    # and test whether the upstream still exists
    git rev-parse $upstream && continue

    # $branch has upstream $upstream which is gone, so:
    echo git branch -D $branch
done
```

This is quite untested, and is missing important bits like keeping it quiet about branches it's *not* going to delete (each `rev-parse` will spew messages to stdout and/or stderr).  It also doesn't actually delete any branches: since that can be rather irrecoverable, so one would want to test it thoroughly first, and only then remove the `echo`.

Comment: I thought you could undelete a branch? I noticed in Github that undelete was an option of a merged branch, so why is a delete irrecoverable?

Comment: @user2012677: You can create a *new* branch, pointing to the same commit as before, but you lose the `[branch "..."]` section from the `.git/config` *and* the reflog. There's progress (slowly) in Git to add "branch undelete" but it's not there yet. GitHub's interface is not Git's.

Comment: so is GitHub not actually deleting my branch?

Comment: @user2012677: GitHub's web interface does whatever they've programmed it to do. Who knows what that is! (Well, GitHub know, of course ... they just don't *tell* us.) In any case they don't offer reflogs, nor upstream settings, so they have a simpler task.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete all branches at one go (except the one which is checked out) by one single command:

```
git branch --list | xargs git branch -D
```

If you want to specify some pattern to match the branch name, you can do that too:

```
git branch --list k* | xargs git branch -D
```

And with the help of

```
git remote prune origin
```

you can delete remote branches in your system that are no longer referenced.

Hope this helps !