# Why does git branch --merged not show all merged branches?

Tags: git

I created a feature branch, then created a PR for it.  My PR was accepted and merged.  The PR says, "the branch can be safely deleted."  But when I do `git branch --merged` on the main branch, I don't see the merged branch.  What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Was the branch squashed or rebased? If so, neither of those will show up in `--merged`.

Comment: No to being squashed/rebased.

Comment: `git pull` on your main branch so that your merged commit appears in your branch's history.

Comment: I have done that - but it's not sufficient.  Still don't see the branch in `git branch --merged`

Comment: I think what was happening was the commiters (different people from me) were taking my branch, adding modifications, and then merging.  When this happens, git branch --merged will not show the original branch as merged.  If someone wants to write this up I'll be glad to award points.

Answer (score 15):

I have been struggling with this also.
We are using [gitlab's MR flow](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/gitlab_flow.html), which is probably the most simple merge based git flow.

What I have noticed is that we select to [Squash Commits](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/squash_and_merge.html) when a MR is merged.
As a consequence this affects git history and prevents the `--merged` flag from working as expected.

Comment: Same issue for me, we used to to proper merges, and ever since we moved to using Rebase & Squash via GitHub Pull Requests, this feature no longer works.

Answer (score 2):

This is a difficult question to answer without knowing the exact workflow.

I assume since you 'created a PR' you forked/cloned a non-local repo to start with. Then you created a new branch in your local repository, made changes to add a feature, and committed those changes onto your local feature branch.

Beyond that it's a bit murkier.  Here are a few steps you might take:

1. You say you submitted a PR, but you don't say that you ever merged the feature branch with your local master branch.  That suggests you may be following a workflow [like this one](https://gist.github.com/vlandham/3b2b79c40bc7353ae95a).  If that's the case, and you're running `git branch --merged` in your *local* repository, the reason you don't see your feature branch listed is that *you never merged your feature branch into master* in your local repository.  This, IMO, is the most likely scenario.  Try running `git pull <name of your remote--probably origin> master` from your local master branch, then trying running `git branch --merged` again.
2. [Fast-forwarding](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/git-fast-forwards-and-branch-management-329977726.html) *could* cause some confusion, though it wouldn't create the issue you're describing on its own.
3. You can always run `git log` on a given branch to see its full commit history.  You could examine the commit history of your master and compare it to the commit history of origin/master to maybe find the discrepancy.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Re: 1 - yes, I never merged it directly back in but I would have thought that when I merged in the changes to the upstream branch that I forked, it would be counted as merged in.  I am even with the upstream branch, and the upstream branch merged  in my change; doesn't that mean I have merged in my change?

Comment: Normally I would think so, yes. Git identifies merged branches by checking if the tip commit of a given branch is accessible in the commit history of the commit you run the branch command on, so the next thing I would do is compare the commit histories of upstream/master and local/master by running git log.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, when feature branches were merged to develop and develop was merged to master. Such branches are not shown for

```
git branch --merged master
```

but shown for

```
git branch --merged develop
```

But it’s better to use -r flag as recommended in [How do I delete all Git branches which have been merged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127328/how-can-i-delete-all-git-branches-which-have-been-merged/24558813#24558813)

Delete remote git branches :

```
git branch -r --merged | grep -v '\*\|master\|develop\|release' | sed 's/origin\///' 
| xargs -n 1 git push --delete origin
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this too, and what I learnt was that **the state of the remote branch before it was merged is different from the remote branch I have**

Instead of using the regular merge, which adds a "merge commit", I was using the [fast-forward merge approach on GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/methods/#fast-forward-merge). And this is where the state of the branches conflicts.

If I want to fast-forward the changes introduced on `testing` on `main`, `testing` would need to already contain all the changes in `main`. But in a case where new changes may have been introduced to `main` since the time `testing` was created, a fast-forward merge cannot happen. `testing` does not contain ALL the changes in `main`.

For a fast-forward to work, I'd first need to rebase `testing` with `main`. [GitLab UI has a rebase button](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/git/git_rebase.html#from-the-gitlab-ui) so I don't need to do that locally.

When I rebase the `testing` branch on remote, before merging to `main`, the `testing` branch would now have a different state, compared to the `testing` branch I have locally (because I didn't also rebase locally). In fact, running `git status` locally, git will tell you that you have **divergent branches** because the histories are different.

So when the remote branch is merged to main on remote, and you pull main, and check for merged local branches, git will not be able to tell that `testing` has been merged:

```bash
git checkout main
git pull origin main
git branch --merged
# will not show testing
```

Why? Because, as I said earlier, **the state of the remote `testing` branch before it was merged is different from the state of the local `testing` branch. Though, you can check if the remote `testing` branch has been merged:

```bash
git branch -r --merged
# origin/testing would show
```

The `r` option shows only remote branches, and by checking the merged remote branches, you would see that the remote `testing` branch (maybe `origin/testing`) is listed.

So how do you verify if the local `testing` branch has been merged? For that, you have to put the local `testing` branch in the same state with the remote `testing` branch.

You can do that by rebasing locally.

**You can either rebase with main**

```bash
git checkout testing
git rebase main
```

Now, `testing` will contain ALL the changes in `main` (which was what caused the difference in states with the remote `testing`) and would put the local and remote branches in the same state.

**Or you can rebase with the remote branch**

```bash
git checkout testing
git rebase origin/testing
```

Same thing happens, the local `testing` branch would be in the same state with the remote `testing` branch.

Now, when you run `git branch --merged` locally, git can verify (because, same states) if the `testing` branch has indeed been merged. If `origin/testing` has been merged, then definitely, `testing` has been merged.

**Note that** it's possible that you did not rebase yourself, but someone working on your branch must have. The main problem here is that the state of the branches have changed and that's why git cannot verify your local branch. Something "happened" to your remote branch which didn't happen to your local branch.

I shared more detail about this [in my article](https://dillionmegida.com/p/why-git-merged-does-not-show-merged-branches/) for further learnings :)