# Single git command to bulk delete unsued branches

Tags: git, unix

I am just  looking for  a git command to  bulk delete  my unused  remote branches.

My requirement is like , i want to delete a merged or unused branches for a particular user for past months.Lets say, A is an user created 10 branches on november and also he created 10 branches on december. Now he wants to delete november branches.

I just  tried with git  for-each-ref for that :

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(committerdate) %09 %(authorname) %09 % \ 
(refname)%09 %(committerdate:relative)' --sort=committerdate  |grep "Rk"
```

Any solutions would be appreciable

Comment: Can you describe more specifically "unused" in your context? What specific criteria should protect a branch from deletion here? *(Your command is (broken, for one thing, but also) purely output, it won't do a thing to your branches, by the way.)*

Comment: Is this duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127328/how-can-i-delete-all-git-branches-which-have-been-merged

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I delete all Git branches which have been merged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127328/how-can-i-delete-all-git-branches-which-have-been-merged)

Comment: @RomainValeri I want to delete an unused branches  which are not used for 1month from current date.For that i am expecting single git  command.

Comment: @RathanaKumar "branches which are not used" is a useless description until we know what "used" means for you. Checking the branch out? Commiting on the branch? Pushing commits on remote version of the branch? Also, are you ok with deleting branches with unmerged commits on it provided they're "old" enough?

Comment: @RomainValeri Assume,to develop a feature, am creating a branch to do some commits and merge, once the feature get  closed ,the branch become unused. In that  way, am creating a new branch for every new feature.Now  the old branches will become unused right. Because of that  am asking a single git command to  clear  out all the branches, instead of finding each branch  and delete.

Comment: @RathanaKumar So the term you were searching for was *merged branches*, it'll be clearer.

Comment: @RomainValeri yes probably !!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a `master` branch as your stable one, a command for bulk deletion of merged branches could look like

```
git checkout master
git branch -d $(git for-each-ref --author=<name> --since="november" --before="december" --format="%(refname:short)" refs/heads)
```

There, no *unmerged* branch (even with given date/author characteristics) will be deleted since you're asking to delete every branch, but with the `-d` flag which won't delete unmerged branches.

Optionnally, you can add `--merged=master` to the `for-each-ref` command, it'll be a little less verbose, avoiding to output the denied deletions.

---

**Note**

Before firing the deletion itself, test the `for-each-ref` part alone, to be sure it outputs what you wanted to be deleted.

Comment: Thanks for the  effort  and solution. but i need to  delete past month branches.is it possible to  do that in this command.

Comment: The date is irrelevant here, **every** branch will be deleted, if its tip (last commit made on the branch) is merged into `master`.

Comment: Fine.. But my requirement is like  , i want to  delete an merged or  unused branches for a particular user for  past months.Lets say, A is user having created 10 branches on november and also  he created 10 branches on december. Now he wants to  delete november branches .does this make sense??

Comment: @RathanaKumar Where is this in your question above? It would be easier to have a clear and complete question stated for everyone, rather than having to read every comment on the page to understand what's the real need.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance.Now i have edited and  stated my question .