# How to clear (delete) all merged local branches?

Tags: git

Sometimes I have a few versions of the same features on other branches which has very similar names.
How can I remove all local branches which are not on remote repo?

**A little example:**
My local branches:

feature/authorization

feature/authorization-2

feature/authorization-with-error

Remote repo branches:

feature/authorization-2

And I want to have only local branch which is on remote repo: feature/authorization-2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I delete all Git branches which have been merged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127328/how-can-i-delete-all-git-branches-which-have-been-merged)

Answer (score 0):

```
git branch --merged
```

you can skip some important branches

```
git branch --merged| egrep -v "(^\*|master|main|dev|skip_branch_name)"
```