# How to delete branches in specific folder?

Tags: git

I have some folders like feature and fix and etc. I want to delete localy all infromation about this branch, because they were already merged and I don't want to see them when call "git branch" or "git branch -r", so the quesation in the titile

Comment: `git branch -d <branchname>` deletes a branch. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Branches aren't in folders. If you mean that you have `br/anch`, `br/anch2`, `br/anch3`, etc., and want to remove all `br/*` branches: you have to do that one by one (well, technically you can generate the complete list and run one `git branch -d` with the list, but it's the same kind of thing anyway). These names resemble folders (and have the same limitations as folders) but aren't actually folders.

Comment: To add to what @torek said, the forward slash '/' in a branch name is just a character of the branch's name. It does not itself group branches together, that is purely up to your interpretation of the names.

Comment: Take a look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127328/how-do-i-delete-all-git-branches-which-have-been-merged

Comment: `git branch -d <Alt-*>` might work, depending on your shell.

Comment: git branch -d <branchname> deletes a branch. Does that answer your question? – 
In that way I must delete branches one by one, but I would like to remove all branches which in feature/*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR

This should do the trick.

```bash
git branch -d $(git branch | grep "^  fix/")
```

#### Explanation

The idea of this is to provide `git branch -d` (delete branch if merged) with a list of all interesting branches, i.e. all branches that start with `"fix/"`.

This list is generated by `git branch | grep "^  fix/"`.
This command is made up of two parts:

1. `git branch`: Lists all local branches (on seperate lines).
2. `grep "^  fix/"`: Only passes lines that begin with `"  fix/"`.

Executing a command `cmd2` with multiple lines of output through `cmd1 $(cmd2)` causes the preceding command `cmd1` to be executed once for each line. Therefore, all matching branches are deleted.

You can of course replace "fix/" with "feature/" or anything else.

---

Note: The two spaces at the start of the line are very important to match. The currently checked out branch is listed beginning with `*` . The asterisk (`*`) tries to match all files in the folder, leading to git trying to delete all branches named like files in the current directory.