# How do I delete all branches in git that are merged into another branch?

Tags: git, branch

I'm not as tidy with my git branches as I could be. One way to clean up branches ([described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127328/how-do-i-delete-all-git-branches-which-have-been-merged)) is:

```bash
git checkout master
git branch --merged # get those branches are merged
git branch -d $branch
```

But that only works for master. Is there an easy way to do this for *all* branches. One approach would be to loop over the branches, but that's starting to feel overcomplicated.

Comment: `--merged` can take an argument : `--merged branch-foo`. So you don't have to switch to each individual branch to see which branches are merged into them. Is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: Looping overt branches is not actually complicated, bash supports writing loops quite easily.