# Git: Delete branch alternative (VSCode)

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-branch

In VSCode, I automatically prune while fetching branches from github. However, branches I locally edited stay on my vscode and the only way I currently know how to remove them is to Git:Delete Branch one at a time in my local machine. I wanted to know if there was a way to automatically delete all these branches so that i didn't have to manually delete twenty branches at once.

Show All Commands (Command+shift+P)
Git: Delete Branch...
Choose a repository
Choose a branch

Comment: Related: [How do I delete all Git branches which have been merged?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6127328/11082165)

Comment: use the command line `git branch -D name1 name2`