# How to refresh the local GIT branches based on latest remote server - in visual studio?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017, team-explorer

I am using visual studio 2017 and GIT.

I can connect to the GIT project, branch and pull the code.

When I make changes to the code, commit, and push to remote server, I have to raise a pull request to merge the code to another branch. Once the pull request succeeds, then the branch gets automatically deleted on the server. But it still exists locally. How do refresh my local branch to have same branches as that of server? I tried fetch but that is not getting rid of local branch (which was deleted from server).

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751582/fetch-from-origin-with-deleted-remote-branches  ? Otherwise you can do as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-locally-and-remotely

Comment: I would like to know how to do this in visual studio team explorer GUI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Team Explorer, go to the Settings page, and then to Git Global Settings.  From there, you can set the "Prune remote branches during fetch" config setting to true.  This will cause all fetches from within VS to prune remote tracking branches (just like explicitly running "git fetch --prune").

This still will not delete your local topic branch, though.  That is your responsibility to delete manually when you're done with it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What does prune mean?

Comment: When the --prune option is passed to fetch, it will delete remote tracking branches from the local repo that no longer exist in the remote repo.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt---prune

Answer (score -1):

This will do it for you:

```
git fetch --prune --all
```

Comment: I would like to know how to do this in visual studio team explorer GUI