# When I type 'git branch -a', it shows red previously deleted branches. Is this normal?

Tags: git, git-branch

I have cloned a remote GitHub repository to my computer, and it all went well. I worked on some branches, and wanted to see all of them, so I typed:

```
git branch -a
```

And it showed this:

```
* master
  remotes/origin/cleanup
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/test
```

I have previously created the 'cleanup' and 'test' branches, merged them, deleted them on the local side, and the remote side, and yet they are showing in this weird 'file-directory like' fashion. Is this normal?

Sorry if this is a bad question. I am new to Git and Github.

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/5751582/3001761?

Comment: Take a look at [remote branching](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches)

Comment: oh... I haven't read this. The title didn't really match what I was thinking, but thanks. Sorry .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fetch from origin with deleted remote branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751582/fetch-from-origin-with-deleted-remote-branches)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to fetch with `--prune` so that deleted remote branches disappear on the local repo (no messing with local branches, even if one local branch was created from one of those deleted remote branches).

```
git fetch --prune -a
```

Comment: Its' solved my problem.