# Delete remote branch displayed on local by 'git branch -a'

Tags: git, github

I'm using GitHub, when I `git branch -a`, it shows like this:

```
  master
* develop
  remotes/origin/HEAD
  remotes/origin/develop
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/feature001
  remotes/origin/feature002
  remotes/origin/feature003
```

I have deleted feature001~003 on GitHub.com, How can I delete them locally? I mean not show when I do `git branch -a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you should just run `git fetch -p` (or `--prune`, same meaning).  However, there's a bug (being fixed) that sometimes requires running `git remote --prune` instead; see [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20106712/1256452).

(If necessary you can delete them manually by using `git update-ref -d` with the full name, or editing the underlying git repository files and directories.)

Answer (score 0):

to delete local branch
    git branch -d the_local_branch

check this link [How do I delete a Git branch both locally and remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remotely)
or you can try pulling from remote and then merge to local repository.