# Make "git remote prune [remoteName]" also prune non-tracking branches?

Tags: git

`git remote prune [remoteName]` is a very handy command that will prune local tracking branches that are no longer on the remote server.  However, is there a way I can also get git to prune the associated local branches at the same time?  So, if it pruned `origin/feature1` and `origin/feature2`, how can I get it to prune `feature1` and `feature2` at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

I think that your question has already been answered in this comment here:
[What are the differences between git remote prune, git prune, git fetch --prune, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20106712/what-are-the-differences-between-git-remote-prune-git-prune-git-fetch-prune#comment40315874_20107184)