# error: cannot lock ref.. 'refs/tags' exists; cannot create 'refs/tags/

Tags: git, github

I'm getting a strange "cannot lock ref" error when trying to pull changes from github.  I've tried git gc, and looked around for similar errors but can't find a solution.

```
> git pull
error: cannot lock ref 'refs/tags/v2.8': 'refs/tags' exists; cannot create 'refs/tags/v2.8'
From github.com:k3it/qsorder
 ! [new tag]         v2.8       -> v2.8  (unable to update local ref)
error: cannot lock ref 'refs/tags/v2.9': 'refs/tags' exists; cannot create 'refs/tags/v2.9'
 ! [new tag]         v2.9       -> v2.9  (unable to update local ref)
```

Comment: This thread might be also helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22630404/git-push-refs-heads-my-subbranch-exists-cannot-create In case you have an existing branch "a" and you are trying to create something like "a/something-else"

Answer (score 167, accepted):

Your Git is complaining that a reference (rather than a directory) named `refs/tags` exists.  It's not clear what would *create* that, but see if `git rev-parse refs/tags` produces a hash ID.  If so, that reference needs to go away:

```
git update-ref -d refs/tags
```

after which `git fetch` should work.

If `git rev-parse refs/tags` fails (which it should—`refs/tags` itself should not be a valid name) then this is *not* the problem and it's not clear what the actual problem is.

Comment: that did it!  I have no idea how I got into this state. but all is good now. thank you.

Comment: git fetch had more errors I managed to fix all automatically in my answer below...

Comment: @ZsoltSzilagy: which error? If you have an exact error message, it's often helpful to quote it. The answer here is for the exact error message quoted in the original question—specifically the phrase `'refs/tags' exists; ...`.

Comment: `git rev-parse refs/tags` does not work anymore, please use the second solution.

Answer (score 134):

Running

```
git remote prune origin
```

Worked for me. Not sure why this was the issue, but seems like there was a broken reference to a remote branch.

Comment: This answer should work for most cases where GIT has accumulated references over the period of time on your machine. This removes objects that are no longer being referenced, it does not remove references. Here is a better explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20106712/what-are-the-differences-between-git-remote-prune-git-prune-git-fetch-prune

Answer (score 18):

`git gc` will solve it!
Cleanup unnecessary files and optimize the local repository
[Link](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc)

Comment: When I had a repo in a stuck state, the other answers did not resolve it but this did.

Answer (score 12):

In my case, the following helped:

```
git fetch --prune origin
git pull
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you.
Adding my exact error
`error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/branchxx': 'refs/remotes/originbranchxx' exists; cannot create 'refs/remotes/origin/branchxx'`

Answer (score 8):

> error: cannot lock ref 'refs/tags/v2.8': 'refs/tags' exists; cannot create 'refs/tags/v2.8'
>   From github.com:k3it/qsorder

Try deleting your local tag `v2.8` and `v2.9` then pull again.

```
$ git tag -d v2.8 
$ git tag -d v2.9

$ git pull
```

---

If you want to delete all local tags by a command:

```
$ git tag | xargs git tag -d
```

Comment: that didn't work. pull gives the same error as above, same for git fetch -p.  i can't push local changes because the remote is ahead and the pull doesn't work

Comment: Worked for me.  Thanks!

Comment: doing it manually for all the tags is a tedious job I managed to generate the delete command automatically in my answer below...

Comment: @TomerBar-Shlomo if you want to delete all the tags by a command: `git tag | xargs git tag -d`

Comment: @SajibKhan You only need to delete tags that where recreated and caused the error

Comment: Deleting all local tags helped. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8):

**First Solution** ==>:let's say you have branch called **develop**  and you're trying to create new branch called **develop/updatefeature** this will cause this error, that was my case so If you remove the develop word from the new branch (***updatefeature***)I think It should be solved the issue.

**Second Solution** ==>: use the below command in bash

```
git remote prune origin
```

Comment: Worked for me, I was having the same case, in my local, I had a branch and later I created a new branch with `branch/ui`, so it was giving me errors, but by renaming the newly created branch fixed this issue. thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me after all other answers didn't

`git update-ref --no-deref -d refs/remotes/origin/branch_name`

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "update-ref delete refs/tags"
log="git-update-ref-errors.log"
script="./git-update-ref-exist-tags-delete.sh"
git_command="git update-ref -d refs/tags"

echo "log errors from ${git_command} to ${log}"
${git_command} 2>&1 | > ${log}
echo "show errors to ${log}"
cat ${log}
echo create ${script}
touch ${script}
echo "add execute (+x) permissions to ${script}"
chmod +x ${script}
echo "generate ${script} from errors log ${log}"
${git_command} 2>&1 | grep 'exists' | sed -n "s:.*\: 'refs/tags/\(.*\)' exists;.*:git tag -d '\1':p" >> ${script}
echo "execute ${script}"
${script}

echo fetch
log="git-fetch-errors.log"
script="./git-fetch-exist-tags-delete.sh"
git_command="git fetch"
echo "log errors from ${git_command} to ${log}"
${git_command} 2>&1 | > ${log}
echo "show errors from ${log}"
cat ${log}
echo create ${script}
touch ${script}
echo "add execute (+x) permissions to ${script}"
chmod +x ${script}
echo "generate ${script} from errors log ${log}"
${git_command} 2>&1 | grep 'exists' | sed -n "s:.*\: 'refs/tags/\(.*\)' exists;.*:git tag -d '\1':p" >> ${script}
echo "execute ${script}"
${script}
git fetch

echo pull
log="git-pull-errors.log"
script="./git-pull-exist-tags-delete.sh"
git_command="git pull"
echo "log errors from ${git_command} to ${log}"
${git_command} 2>&1 | > ${log}
echo "show errors from ${log}"
cat ${log}
echo create ${script}
touch ${script}
echo "add execute (+x) permissions to ${script}"
chmod +x ${script}
echo "generate ${script} from errors log ${log}"
${git_command} 2>&1 | grep 'exists' | sed -n "s:.*\: 'refs/tags/\(.*\)' exists;.*:git tag -d '\1':p" >> ${script}
echo "execute ${script}"
${script}
git pull
```

The script above will log errors to XXX-errors.log and fix them by generating and running a XXX-exist-tags-delete.sh automatically from the XXX-errors.log using the following commands:

1. git update-ref -d refs/tags
2. git fetch
3. git pull

Answer (score 0):

For a quick work around you can use

`git push --delete origin 'v2.8'`

`git push --delete origin 'v2.9'`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I tried and it worked for me.

```
git remote prune origin
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to push (/dev/somechanges) and  I have a remote branch (/dev) with the same prefix 
when I choose a new name that is not starting with /dev it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I tried `git update-ref -d refs/tags` and `git remote prune origin` but nothing worked.

My command was `git checkout -b test/revert_code`, so finally, I recognized that the problem is not the git, but my command itself. When I removed "`test/`", it worked as normal. So my final command was `git checkout -b revert_code`.

Maybe this is just a rare case, but hope this help anyone who have tried all solutions above but hadn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the specific file in folder

```
C:\git\repo\.git\logs\refs\remotes\origin\secops
```

Answer (score 0):

For those using a Jenkins Pipeline:

- under `Pipeline script from SCM`,
- go to `Additional Behaviors` and
- add the `Prune stale remote-tracking branches` step which will

> Run "git remote prune" for each remote, to prune obsolete local branches.

This way, the job will fix the error in the git repo before trying to checkout the branch to build from.

Kudos to the git devs because the error message gives the exact solution!

Example log with the error in question:

```
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from MY_GIT_REPO_ADDRESS
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:999)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1241)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1305)
    ...
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git.exe fetch --tags --force --progress -- MY_GIT_REPO_ADDRESS +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 1:
stdout: 
stderr: error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/MY_NEW_BRANCH': 'refs/remotes/origin/MY_OLD_BRANCH' exists; cannot create 'refs/remotes/origin/MY_NEW_BRANCH'
From MY_GIT_REPO_ADDRESS
 ! [new branch]      MY_NEW_BRANCH -> origin/MY_NEW_BRANCH  (unable to update local ref)
error: some local refs could not be updated; try running
 'git remote prune MY_GIT_REPO_ADDRESS to remove any old, conflicting branches
```