# git remote prune origin does not delete the local branch even if its upstream remote branch is deleted

Tags: git, git-branch, git-remote

This is a common use-case for me, I clone a repository, checkout a branch, do some code changes, make multiple commits, then when it's stable, I do a push to remote, eventually the branch gets merged and deleted, and I'm left with a local branch with upstream gone.

I was looking for a safe way of deleting all such branches. From the description, it seemed like `git remote prune origin` is doing this exactly. But it doesn't seem to be working for me.

Seeing the following behaviour, the branch `encrdb_init` has been deleted from `remote` but the `git remote prune origin` command does not seem to prune it. I am not sure why.

```
$ git branch
  bugfix/encrdb_init
  * master
$
$ git remote prune origin
$
$ git checkout bugfix/encrdb_init
  Switched to branch 'bugfix/encrdb_init'
  Your branch is based on 'origin/bugfix/encrdb_init', but the upstream 
  is gone.
  (use "git branch --unset-upstream" to fixup)
$
$ git branch
  bugfix/encrdb_init <<< shouldn't this have been pruned?
  * master
```

for reference adding output of `git remote show origin`

```
$ git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: <redacted>
  Push  URL: <redacted>
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    SSL_test                                                  tracked
    addNodeFix                                                tracked
    autoprefix                                                tracked
    release/1.0.2                                             tracked
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    bugfix/encrdb_init          merges with remote bugfix/encrdb_init
    master                      merges with remote master
    release/1.0.2               merges with remote release/1.0.2
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    master                 pushes to master                 (up to 
date)
    release/1.0.2          pushes to release/1.0.2          (up to 
date)

$ git branch -vv
* bugfix/encrdb_init          341a078c [origin/bugfix/encrdb_init: gone] <redacted comment>`
```

Comment: Try `git remote prune origin --dry-run` to check the stale branches

Comment: `git remote prune origin --dry-run` output is empty

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri it returns empty because there is no more remote tracking branch to delete. And  `bugfix/encrdb_init` is a *local* one (you can have a slash in a branch name)

Comment: you should receive a list of `your stale remote-tracking branches` with the above command. If you don't receive it, something else is probably wrong

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the differences between git remote prune, git prune, git fetch --prune, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20106712/what-are-the-differences-between-git-remote-prune-git-prune-git-fetch-prune)

Comment: Thanks, it looks like the command only deletes the branches in `remote` but does not delete the local branch which is now left hanging. It looks like the command does not delete local branches, even the ones which have upstream gone.

Comment: @saketrp yes, that is the all point of `git remote`: to update or delete in the *`remotes`* namespace. Not to tamper with local branches.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the actual commands that will delete the branches you want.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The **[`git remote prune`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote.html#git-remote-empruneem)** command only deletes the remote tracking branches in the `remotes/origin` namespace.

Not the local branches.
The usual practice is to [delete only *merged* local branches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28464339/6309).

git branch (even with -vv) only shows *local* branches.
A [branch can have a slash in its name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2527436/6309)

A remote tracking branch is in the `remotes/origin` namespace, and record what was fetch.
An **[upstream branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6244487/6309)** is a remote branch associated to a local branch in order for said local branch to know *where* to push.

git remote prune correctly remove the remote tracking branch, which happens to be the upstream branch for the local `bugfix/encrdb_init`  branch.
That is why you see `origin/bugfix/encrdb_init: gone`: the remote tracking branch is gone.

---

The OP adds:

> from the description, it seemed like `git remote prune origin` is doing this exactly. But it doesn't seem to be working for me.

No, the description does not mention local branches.

> Deletes all stale remote-tracking branches under `<name>`.
>   These stale branches have already been removed from the remote repository referenced by `<name>`, but are still locally available in "`remotes/<name>`".

`<name>` here is the name of the *remote* repo referenced by git remote -v.
Usually "`origin`".
`git remote prune` will delete branches registered in `remotes/origin` (not the "remote(s)"). It will not delete local branches.

To "safely" delete local branches, you should:

- either considered the [ones that are merged locally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27412626/6309), for instance merged to `master`:

  ```
  git fetch -p && git branch -d $(git branch master --merged | grep master -v)
  ```
- or, if you really want to [delete immediately the one whose upstream branch is "gone"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33548037/6309):

  ```
  git fetch -p && for branch in `git branch -vv | grep ': gone]' | awk '{print $1}'`; do git branch -D $branch; done
  ```

That last option is flaky:

- I prefer using git branch -d instead of -D, in order to delete only branches that are already merged.
- you might end up deleting branches with a commit message contains the string "`: gone`"

A [better way to list those branches is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48411554/6309):

```
git branch --list --format "%(if:equals=[gone])%(upstream:track)%(then)%(refname)%(end)"
```

Comment: OP is trying `git remote prune origin` which should delete stale branches from the  local, your answer doesn not answer the question

Comment: Yes, the branch `bugfix/encrdb_init` has been merged to master and deleted at remote, but git does not delete it.

Comment: @saketrp my answers stands: git remote prune won't delete a local branch. bugfix/encrdb_init is a local branch.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri my answer stands.

Comment: Isn't it a tracking branch? as evident from the output of `git remote show origin`

Comment: @saketrp no it is not.

Comment: @VonC How can I see this?  Even the verbose command output shows this, doesn't it mean its a tracking branch?

Comment: git branch alone gives you local branches only. It shows you a local branch and mentions its upstream branch is gone.

Comment: @saketrp I have to go to work, I will catch up later. In the meantime, my answer stands.

Comment: Sure, but isn't a local branch with upstream same as a tracking branch? and isn't this command supposed to delete such branches where upstream is gone? If not, what is the exact purpose of this command?

Comment: @saketrp I just edited the answer to add links and references