# Effects of git remote update origin --prune on local changes

Tags: git

**Please note**: I first took a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20106712/what-are-the-differences-between-git-remote-prune-git-prune-git-fetch-prune) hoping it would answer my question, but I think mine is *slightly* different!

---

I was told that running `git remote update origin --prune` locally would force my local repo to have the exact same branches as the origin repo. However I can find *loads* of info/documentation surrounding the use of `git remote prune origin`, but not `git remote update origin --prune`...

Is my understanding of this command correct? If not, how am I misled? And if I am correct, then what happens if I have local feature branches that haven't been pushed remotely yet? What happens if I have changes to branches that *do* existing remotely/on the origin but have I have not pushed those changes yet?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Apparently you are reading the wrong documentation. Read about [`git remote update`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#Documentation/git-remote.txt-emupdateem) on the official Git documentation (or just type `git help remote` in your console).

Comment: I suggest you read about the difference between a local branch and a remote tracking branch.

Comment: Thanks @axiac (+1) but in that link the mention of the `--prune` flag reads "_With --prune option, run pruning against all the remotes that are updated_"...so does that mean: (1) any local branches that don't exist on the origin/remote are delete? and (2) that any uncommitted changes on local branches that do exists on the origin/remote are left alone? Thanks again!

Comment: *"any uncommitted changes on local branches..."* -- branches are in repo, uncommitted changes are not in repo but only on your local working tree. `git remote` doesn't care about the local changes. It operates only on the remotes and on the information about the branches on the remote repos that your local repo caches.

Comment: Man, I feel like I'm pulling teeth here! What does `git remote update origin --prune` do?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

#### TL;DR

The `git remote update remote` command is *the same* as the `git fetch remote` command.  (There were some bugs in some versions of Git that made them different, but they are supposed to do the same thing.)  With `--prune`, the update process simply *removes* any remote-tracking names that exist in your repository, but no longer correspond to a branch name in the repository at *`remote`*.

#### Long

> I was told that running `git remote update origin --prune` locally would force my local repo to have the exact same branches as the origin repo.

That's not quite right.  Well, that's not *at all* right, really.  And this does tie in to the way you've phrased your question title:

> Effects ... on local changes

When using Git, it's important to recognize several things that are odd / different-from most other version control systems.  The first is that branches, or branch *names* more precisely, don't really matter that much.  Branch names like `master` and `develop` are mostly just for use by humans, and you can do pretty much anything you want with them, including changing them around arbitrarily.  (There are a few exceptions that we'll get to in a bit.)

What you *can't* change—and what really matters to Git—are commit *hash IDs*.  You will have seen these things in `git log` output: they're big ugly number-and-letter strings like [`b5101f929789889c2e536d915698f58d5c5c6b7a`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b5101f929789889c2e536d915698f58d5c5c6b7a), which is a commit in the Git repository for Git.  These numbers (these are actually hexadecimal representations) are unique and universal: every Git everywhere will use *that number* for *that commit*.  If you're not working with a clone of this particular Git repository, you won't have that commit.  If you *are* working with a clone of this particular Git repository and *don't* have this commit, your Git just needs to connect to another Git that *does* have this commit, and you'll get this commit.

These numbers are how Git identifies and finds commits.  They're what Git really cares about: the commits themselves, and these unique hash IDs to identify them.

Each commit contains some number of other, earlier commits' hash IDs.  Usually each commit has just one earlier commit hash ID.  That one earlier commit ID is the *parent* of the commit.  So given some commit hash ID, your Git can tell if you have the commit.  If so, your Git can fish out the *parent* hash ID, and tell if you have *that* commit, and then fish out *its* parent ID, and so on.  What this means is that given any one commit (by hash ID), your Git can find *all* the commits, one by one, working backwards.  This makes for an easy way to draw them:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

where `H` stands in for some commit hash.  Git will find the actual commit, read out its parent hash ID `G`, read the commit, find its parent `F`, and so on.  The action stops when Git gets back to the very first commit ever made, which has *no* parent hash.

Nothing in any commit can ever change.  (In part, that's because the actual hash ID is a cryptographic checksum of all of the contents of the commit.  If you were to change anything—even a single bit—you'd get a new, different hash for a new, different commit.)  So since `H` store's `G`'s hash ID, `H` will always, forever, point back to `G`.  The one-way-ness of the connecting arrows is therefore mostly irrelevant and we can stop drawing them; we just need to remember that Git itself has to work backwards.

A *branch name*, like `master` or `develop`, is just a way that your Git offers to let you help remember one of these hash IDs.  It only remembers *one* of them!  The one it remembers is, *by definition*, the *latest* one.  If you change the number associated with your `master`, you've told your Git: *Use a different commit as the latest one.*  Hence we augment the picture a bit:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

Thus, the hash ID in `H` is that of the *last* commit that Git should treat as being "on" branch `master`.

When you make a *new* commit, starting with `git checkout master` and doing all the usual stuff up to the point where you run `git commit`, Git writes out a new commit.  This new commit gets a new, unique hash ID, which we can call `I`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I
```

Having written out the commit and found its cryptographic-checksum hash ID, Git now writes that hash ID into the name `master`, so that `master` points to `I`:

```
...--F--G--H
            \
             I   <-- master
```

and now `I` is the tip commit of `master`.  You / your Git can still find commit `H`, by starting at `I` and walking back one step.

If something were to overwrite your `master` and make it point back to `H`, it would become very difficult to *find* commit `I`, because the internal arrows all point backwards.  `I` points to `H`—the child knows its parent—but `H` has no idea that `I` exists at all.  (It didn't when whoever made `H`, made it, and `H` can't change now!)

For this reason (among other reasons), your branch names are *yours*.  No one but you and your Git can write new numbers into them.  The hash IDs of actual commits are unique and universal: if someone else makes a new commit, that new commit gets a new hash ID that no other commit will ever have, and your Git will know if you have that commit or not.  If you need it, your Git will get it from their Git when you connect your Git to their Git.  But your branch names are *yours*.

So `git fetch` or `git remote update`—again, both do the same thing—will call up some *other* Git, and get any new commits from them that you don't have.  Let's say you `git fetch origin` to call up a Git at the URL you're calling `origin`.  If you added commit `I` to your `master`, and they added commit `J` to *theirs*, your Git now has:

```
...--F--G--H--J   <-- ???
            \
             I   <-- master
```

How will your Git *find* commit `J`?  Writing that hash ID into your `master` is obviously a bad idea: that loses `I`!  So where *can* your Git write that hash ID?

Git's answer to this is *remote-tracking names* (which most people call *remote-tracking branches*, but I think Git already uses the word *branch* too much).  Your Git's name, with which your Git remembers `origin`'s `master`, is `origin/master`, and the picture should read:

```
...--F--G--H--J   <-- origin/master
            \
             I   <-- master
```

If you want to add commit `I`—or another different commit that's just as good—to *their* master, you now have to decide, do you really want `I` itself, or another commit that's just as good?  If you want to keep `I` itself, you'd merge `I` and `J` to make a new commit that has two parents:

```
...--F--G--H--J   <-- origin/master
            \  \
             I--M   <-- master
```

Since merge commit `M` has arrows back to *both* `J` *and* `I`, you can now send them commit `M` and ask their Git to set *their* `master` to point to commit `M`.

#### Your Git has a remote-tracking name for each of their branches

When you run `git fetch origin` or `git remote update origin`, your Git calls up the other Git at `origin` and asks for a list of all of its branches.  Their branches are of course *theirs*, but your Git would like to get any new commits they've made and remember the latest one for you.  So if they have `master`, `develop`, `feature/A`, and `feature/B`, your Git gets any commits they have that you don't and remembers *their* branch tips under your `origin/*` names, corresponding to their branch names:

```
                L--N   <-- origin/feature/A
               /
...--F--G--H--J   <-- origin/master
            \
             I   <-- master
```

If they've deliberately removed some commit(s) from some of their branches by writing an older hash ID into their branch name(s), your Git will adjust your remote-tracking branches correspondingly.  In some cases, this may result in your Git forgetting their commits (if you've never bothered to make your own names to save them):

```
                  N   [abandoned]
                 /
                L   <-- origin/feature/A
               /
...--F--G--H--J   <-- origin/master
            \
             I   <-- master
```

Commit `N` is no longer findable, and eventually `git gc` will remove it entirely from your repository.  (This is where branch names, or other names, become important: they not only let you *find* the commits, they also *protect* the tip commit from the Grim <strike>Reaper</strike> Collector.  Those tip commits protect their parents, who protect commits further back in the chain, all the way to the root commit.)

Suppose, though, that at some point they decide that feature `A` is finished.  They have merged it back into their master, or *fast-forwarded* their master to point to it directly:

```
...--F--G--H--J--L   <-- master, feature/A   [no origin/ -- this is THEIR Git!]
```

which in your Git is:

```
...--F--G--H--J--L   <-- origin/master, origin/feature/A
            \
             I   <-- master
```

They may now *delete* their `feature/A` name entirely.  When they do, your Git stops seeing *new* values for your `origin/feature/A`.

Without `--prune`, however, your Git *doesn't remove your `origin/feature/A`.  So you continue to remember `origin/feature/A` as specifying commit `L`.  This doesn't do any real harm; you'll just think, based on looking at your `origin/*` names, that they still have `feature/A` and that it means commit `L`.

Whether to use `--prune` is up to you.  I turn it on automatically in my own Git configuration; this keeps my repositories less-cluttered.

Comment: How can such a detailed answer only have 20 Up Votes... +1!