# git post delete hook?

Tags: git, github, version-control

My home computer is behind a corporate VPN firewall and is not accessible from outside.

I am trying to keep my github repo as identical as possible to my desktop's repo.

I have the following hooks:

`.git/hooks/post-commit`: `git push origin *:*`

Now I realize that if I checkout a branch, commit, and merge that branch into master, I will have a "dangling" remote branch because the commit would have created that branch.

I tried googling for a "post-delete-branch" hook to call `git push origin :$(branch)` but git does not provide this hook.

What can I do to remove dangling branches?

Comment: the `--mirror` switch to `push` is probably what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add to your current post-commit hook a script cleaning up local branches and pushing those deletions (like in this [blog post](http://devblog.springest.com/a-script-to-remove-old-git-branches/)):

```
git branch —merged master | grep -v ‘master$’ | xargs git branch -d

echo “The following remote branches are fully merged into master and will be removed:” git branch -r —merged master | sed ’s/ *origin\///‘ | grep -v ‘master$’

read -p “Continue (y/n)? ” 
if [ “$REPLY” == “y” ] then 
    # Remove remote fully merged branches 
    git branch -r —merged master | sed ’s/ *origin\///‘ | grep -v ‘master$’ | xargs -I% git push origin :% 
    echo “Done!” say “Obsolete branches are removed” 
fi
```

That way, at the next commit, any branch previously merge will be deleted both locally and on the remote side.
See "[How to delete a Git branch both locally and remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23961231/6309)".

---

Don't forget at home to do a:

```
git fetch --prune
```

That will clean up local branches which are no longer present on the remote side.
See "[git remote branch deleted but still appears in '`branch -a`'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12197344/6309)"

Comment: everything works perfectly if this is added to the post-merge hook. Note that some characters pasted here are escaped incorrectly by HTML. (watch out for ', ", --).