# How do we remove branches that no longer exist from the auto complete in Git?

Tags: git, github, terminal, iterm2

[image]

^ For example, you can see that after I run `git br` (alias for `git branch`)

I no longer have the `fix/add-themed-validation` branch, I deleted it.

However when I try to check out a different branch with a similar name, the `fix` branch is in my auto complete.

Comment: This seems more related to you shell interpreter than git

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git remote branch deleted but still appears in 'branch -a'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094293/git-remote-branch-deleted-but-still-appears-in-branch-a)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+stale+branches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That probably the one from a remote (e.g. origin). You need to remove that one from the remote and "prune"

```
git fetch --prune
```