# How do I list all local tracking branches not pushed in git?

Tags: git, branch

I'm working in a git repository on multiple tracking branches, and by the end of the day I don't know if I pushed all my work in all branches.

Is there a git command showing which branches are not pushed, so I can checkout and make the pull, merging if necessary and then push?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assumption (or definition): by *tracking branch* you mean a branch which has an upstream set, *and* that upstream refers to a remote-tracking name.  For instance, if branch `develop` has `origin/develop` as its upstream, that one counts; but if branch `test` has `develop` set as its upstream, that one does not count.

A possible command sequence to use in this case is:

```
git fetch
```

followed by:

```
git branch -vv | grep origin/
```

The output will resemble this:

```
* master          083378cc35 [origin/master] commit subject line
  xyz             8dbdf339cd [origin/xyz: ahead 1, behind 13] another subject line
```

which tells us that `master` is up to date but `xyz` is out of sync with its remote counterpart.

Note that if the upstream in question is not named `origin`, you will need to change the `grep` command accordingly.  You may also need more than one `git fetch`, or you may want to use `git fetch --all`.  (You may also want to use `git fetch --prune` or set `fetch.prune` to `true`, but this is independent of everything else here.)

---

It's possible to write a fancier script that prints only the *names*, skips branches that are in sync, and so on.  If you want to do that, use `git for-each-ref` to enumerate references in the `refs/heads/` namespace.  These are your branch names.  For each name, test whether it has an upstream setting and if so, get the hash ID of its upstream.  Compare that to the hash ID of the branch.  Also, check whether the upstream is a *local* branch (the `test` example above, where the upstream is `develop`) or a remote-tracking name.

If the upstream *is* a remote-tracking name and the hash IDs of the local name and the upstream differ, the branch is out of sync with its remote counterpart.  To get the ahead and/or behind counts, use:

```
git rev-list --count --left-right local...upstream
```

The ahead count will be the first number printed and the behind count will be the second.

Comment: The assumption is absolutely correct, and let's that `git branch -vv | grep origin/` is enough to see which branches are to be pushed to their remote counterparts