# How to remove non-existent Git remote references created in error

Tags: git

I was trying to fetch open PR's by running this command but I've created refs that are completely invalid:

```
git fetch origin '+refs/pull/*/merge:refs/remotes/$rem/open-pr/*'
```

Now I can't delete them. They exist when running `git branch -r`:

```
  $rem/open-pr/139
  $rem/open-pr/164
  $rem/open-pr/165
  $rem/open-pr/168
```

I've tried deleting through a number of ways to no avail.

```
git fetch --prune
git branch -D '$rem/open-pr/139'
git branch -d '$rem/open-pr/139'
git remote prune origin
```

Comment: AFAIU `$rem` is a literal here, not a placeholder? `git branch -d -r '$rem/open-pr/139'` See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5096739/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+delete+remote-tracking+branch

Comment: That was it, forgot the `-r`